# Cannot upgrade, "could not download the release notes" error

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, internet, connection

here is happening  everytime after I click the Upgrade button at Update Manager
fyi, my internet connection is ok because my Gwibber is always working and giving me the latest tweet
and also i can surf well.
but the internet connection always suddenly cut whenever I try to Upgrade.

[image]

Comment: I think this is just timing out due to the load on the servers, might want to wait a bit and see if it's still an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Natty is just out, the servers are a bit crowded.

Consider the next traffic graph for the default [Dutch Ubuntu mirror](http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/):
[image: mirror traffic]

The traffic has been increased by four times because of the new Ubuntu release. Switching to a less used mirror improved the download speed for me. A list of mirrors, sorted by country, can be found at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

See also [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me?](https://askubuntu.com/q/37753/6969)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting that error a fair bit last night. Just try again. Eventually the download will succeed.

Comment: No, it's an answer. The solution to the problem is to try again.