# Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error

Tags: apt

When I check for updates, I get a "Failed To Download Repository Information" error.

This is what comes up under details:

```
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_natty_main_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch, 
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 542, accepted):

Just remove all the content of `/var/lib/apt/lists` directory:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: If you remove all files, you have to download them again. You can just remove the invalid file to make this process faster.

Comment: I remember this happening with Debian, too. The solution was to switch repositories (eg, from us.ubuntu.com to XX.ubuntu.com where XX is your country code) or waiting. The best idea would be to wait a bit and retry later. Removing the lists might fix broken lists, but that's rarely the case.

Comment: Old question, but on some distros (Like emdebian), after doing this you'll need to "`mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial`" (As root, obviously.), or else you cannot "`apt-get update`" or otherwise use apt.

Comment: @Behrang: No, you'll not need to download them again. Running **sudo apt-get update** will populate /var/lib/apt/lists again with the repos along with the list of packages they contain.

Comment: @AlyssaGono if it's a folder, you need to run rm with the recursive flag like so: `sudo rm -R /var/lib/apt/lists/*` however, even doing that didn't work for me.

Comment: We need prefix **-rf**, so it will look like `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

Comment: Worked for me, installing a brand new Ubuntu 12.04 AMD64 VM (because I need PHP 5.3). Thanks!

Comment: After doing this, in order to solve my problem, I had to change the update server, which in my case was the portuguese. Changed it to the main one and done update and it worked.

Comment: As suggested by Cam/realhu, this can be done in combination with `sudo apt-get clean` -- that's what worked for me.

Comment: ***It is very important to make a note: this sometimes happens when you query a mirror and it's in the middle of updating from the other mirrors***.  In those cases, you just have to ***wait*** until the syncs are done and try again later.

Comment: This worked great for me. It has been weeks that I had `E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/cm.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz  Hash Sum mismatch` after and `apt update` + `apt upgrade`

Comment: This is all so idiosyncratic voodoo

Comment: I tried this command but still getting Hash Sum error: _E: Failed to fetch http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/c309de7299ec2582c77c7f97351db3f48198f579fea7b9af13f284e5621f0630  Hash Sum mismatch
_

Comment: After doing this Ubuntu Software shows only a couple of apps I can install. Also `apt install ..` gives error because dependencies are not installable

Comment: I'm wondering if there's some related issues, so I'll share here exactly what I did because I had an extra step:
`sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status`
`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`
`sudo apt-get clean`
`sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz`

Comment: But, after that I still couldn't upgrade. Come to find out I had bad memory. To confirm this, I rebooted the machine and used the bios diagnostic tool.

Comment: I also used the command `sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz` before it worked for me (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1785778)

Comment: with a quite similar problem i found the sub-folder 'partial' to have some files there for the dangling repo in question. after deleting only the files for the server in this subfolder all worked nice again.

Comment: just i run `sudo apt upgrade` and then `sudo apt update` and the thing were fixed

Comment: This is unbelievably stupid. Can the OS just be instructed to re-download the broken metadata?

Comment: The only thing that worked for me was to switch from 4G connection (Hotspot) to my Wifi!

Comment: I had to run `apt-get update --fix-missing` then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 136):

This is a known issue, and is exacerbated for clients behind proxy caches. Some large organisations and ISPs (especially in remote parts of the world) have transparent caches of which you may not be aware.

The fundamental issue is that the apt repository format is subject to race conditions when a mirror is updated. This problem particularly affects repositories that change rapidly, such as the development release.

You can track progress on the fix for this in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/972077) (please mark yourself as "affects me too" in the bug) and [this blueprint](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/servercloud-q-apt-improvements). But be aware that it is a complex issue and may take more than one release to resolve.

Comment: [That blueprint](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/servercloud-q-apt-improvements) is no longer accessible; here's [an archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20120512155146/https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/servercloud-q-apt-improvements).

Comment: this bug also exists on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: The bug has been marked as "Fix Released".

Comment: I just change my mirror default to the best server and its work for me.

Comment: @habibun what do you mean by best server?
I'm still facing to this issue even it's marked as Resolved.

Do you guys have any workaround? 
none of `apt-get clean`, `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` work for me even combined

Comment: @irzhy software & updates -> download from -> Other -> select best server

Comment: @habibun not sure that will work in my case.
I'm facing this issue while building a docker image based on debian stretch, a **temporary fix** actually was to removing the security updates repository (which I think is not really a good idea) but at least it make process straighforward

Answer (score 124):

The easiest way to fix this is:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: After trying the accepted answer I still had the same errors, trying this immediately afterwards fixed the issue

Comment: Doing `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` then `sudo apto-get clean` fixed the problem for me also. Neither worked in isolation.

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Comment: does not help on ubuntu 16.04 ... neither does the comment above help any

Comment: @ScottStensland  If you are still having trouble, you can switch to the main server instead of using the server for your nation or area.

Comment: `sudo apt-get clean` did not help with 16.04, but `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` fixed it

Comment: did not work for me.

Comment: For me, accepted answer did not work, but this one worked (Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: This worked for me without doing `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

Comment: I had a few mismatches, and found it took a few repetitions of `clean` and `update` to fix them all.

Comment: @jamesinc same here. this is not something that makes one trust the update mechanism. Feels very shaky.

Comment: This worked for me :)

Comment: This solution worked for me, I needed to run it on a docker build where I have no sudo.

Comment: none of these worked for me

Comment: **Ubuntu 20.04**,  `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` then `sudo apto-get clean` worked. In my case it seems the problem was produced by VirtualBox

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS without the `sudo rm...` stuff.

Comment: This answer works for me too on ubuntu 22 LTS

Answer (score 82):

The only solution that worked for me is from [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273441/41923).

It happens because there's a known bug it apt, and the solution is to update with a different compression method, so the files load correctly and the checksum succeeds.

Give this a try:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz
```

(thanks @brook_hong from the comments for the rm part)

Comment: This is the only solution here that worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: It worked for me too. Note that you don't have to always run this command. Just run it once, and then you can run "apt-get update" without error.

Comment: Before try with the option, we must clean the partial folder -- `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial`. I wrote an article for why.

https://brookhong.github.io/2016/10/10/troubleshoot-hash-sum-mismatch-of-apt-get.html

Comment: I tried using the generic solution from various forums but this works out of the box. Thank you.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04/linux mint

Comment: This is the only solution worked for me, am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I upgraded ubuntu 16 to 18 and received hash mismatch error for some i386 packages. I'm trying to install steam. Only this method worked for me. Can you explain this command? What makes it?

Comment: I did explain in my answer. The command changes the compression method.

Comment: @AmirUval what is the default compression method?

Comment: @vikarjramun If you're here - then your default is probably LZMA (.xz) compression, which has this problem

Comment: @AmirUval Yes, I had the same problem as the question, and your solution fixed it. Would it be in my best interest to revert to xzip using `sudo apt update -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=xz`? I know xzip has a better compression ratio but how marginal is it for deb packages? (19.04 if it matters)

Comment: xz is better, but I wouldn't spend too much time optimising something that is good enough.

Comment: @AmirUval I'm back again, this time with the exact same problem :). I tried switching back to xz, and back to gz again, but neither work. What other encodings can I try? Also, what is a good permanent solution to this problem?

Comment: @vikarjramun I cannot reproduce the problem you have. If I'll see the problem again I will post an update.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04. I don't understand why would the default apt configuration cause this. This is madness, I lost 1h of valuable work time because of this.

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: It should be accepted one

Answer (score 56):

I still had the problem after removing the directories and doing `sudo apt-get update`.
Only the following step solved my problem:

```
sudo sed -i -re 's/\w+\.archive\.ubuntu\.com/archive.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I don't know if this is the right way of fixing it...
I've found the solution [here](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/ploetzliches-problem-mit-aktualisierungen/).

Comment: This was the only solution that works for me with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. Thanks!

Comment: I kept getting this problem with "hirsute-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata" on Ubuntu 21.04, tried all the other answer and nothing worked... this solved it! Thanks @m13r!

Answer (score 25):

This can happen when your mirror is not up to date or serving errors from being overloaded. You can either wait a while and try again, or switch to another mirror:

- [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)

Comment: Why does a server not being up to date, or being overloaded, cause a file with the correct name to *successfully* download (in the sense that the connection doesn't terminate until all the bytes are sent and received), but be corrupted? (I'm not asserting that doesn't happen, I'm just hoping you might be able to explain why it does.)

Comment: @EliahKagan The problem normally is not that the file itself is corrupted, but that there is a (I am simplifying but not too much) data file and an index file containing the hash (fingerprint) of the data file. When the repositories are updated (happens every hour) on the server one file after the other gets updated. Now it can happen that your client (apt-get or similar) accesses the server when the data file has been updated but the index file has not been updated (or vice versa), yet. Then the hash doesn't match the data file and the client (falsely) assumes that the data file is corrupted.

Comment: Changing the mirror worked for me when none of the above answers did.

Answer (score 16):

If you're behind a proxy, then create a file named `99fixbadproxy` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99fixbadproxy
```

Paste this into `99fixbadproxy` and save it:

```
Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth 0;
Acquire::http::No-Cache true;
Acquire::BrokenProxy    true;
```

Now run the update command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Wow, I was trying every answer, it is weird how many different issues seem to result in the same symptom.

Comment: I am much indebted to this answer

Comment: I had to do 'sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' before 'sudo apt-get update' to make it work.

Comment: no luck even with this advice :/

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. But @Musaffa I would like to know what these three lines actually do. Would you please explain?

Answer (score 10):

The [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/41618/333672) will rarely work if you have an issue with the CDN (content delivery network—the caches/mirrors around the world containing the apt lists and packages). It will work if a) you are using a [PPA](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983/333672) or local mirrors or b) have just a single mismatch to resolve.

> *Note: if you have the specific error message given in the log in the question above, the accepted answer should always work. But there are several other questions that have been closed as duplicates of this one where the accepted answer is insufficient.*

It doesn't hurt to try, though, so start with:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

This *might* be sufficient to proceed with `sudo apt-get upgrade` or other follow-up commands.

### But if it doesn't work...

You may get "Hash sum mismatch" errors from *that* command, too. If this happens, run:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

It is possible that even *this* command will throw "Hash sum mismatch" errors, because the issue can come from transient network content errors. If so, continue to re-run the above `--fix-missing` command until it completes successfully. For example, like:

```
until sudo apt-get update --fix-missing; do echo trying again; done
```

(It should make progress with each run of `apt-get update --fix-missing`; if successive runs are not reducing the errors towards zero, press <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> to interrupt the loop. Then go back to the beginning of this answer with removing the contents of `/var/lib/apt/lists` and try again.)

After this, the update may work, but to be sure, first run `apt-get clean`, as so:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Note that if you're doing this in preparation for an `apt-get upgrade`, it is possible (even likely, if you had enough mismatches to require updating several times) the upgrade will fail with "Hash sum mismatch" errors of its own. If so, add `--fix-missing` to your upgrade command:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing
```

and try again. (`apt-get upgrade` with `--fix-missing` will also try holding back failing packages and continuing others, so you should see some additional progress from running this at least once.)

### But if it still doesn't work...

Like the earlier `until sudo...` command, you may get *some* further progress by repeating this command (always preceded by the `clean` command above), which you can even automate with

```
until (sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing --yes); do echo trying again; done
```

but, usually, it will upgrade most of the upgradable packages the first time you run it with `--fix-missing` and after that get stuck on the same packages, making no further progress. At that point, you'll need to go back up to the beginning with the `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and try again. It is worth trying this whole process two or three times, especially if you have dozens or hundreds of upgradable packages.

Answer (score 5):

The following commands may solve your issue.

```
sudo rm -R /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

it will solve your problem. I also faced the same problem but the above commands solved the problem for me. So give them a try.

[Solution reference](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1905494&p=11593258#post11593258)

Comment: I just tried, and it did not work; The first `apt-get update` created files in the same place again in that directory.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem and all solutions provided using the terminal did not help.

For me, it was by going into:

Settings → Software & Updates → Ubuntu Software: Download from: `Change Local` to `Main Server`.

It starts reloading the repos and updating. When I enter:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After that, there was no problem at all. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.

Comment: After changing Updates Download server to `Main` restart the computer and then run `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt update` . 
This fixed the issue in Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that it's proper solution or not, but I did the following and the error message's gone:

After typing `sudo apt-get update` in terminal, it gives me the names of some packages which cause the error then I did the following:

Update manager(software update) → Setting → Configure Software Sources → Other software[tab] → Uncheck the packages

After pressing the "close" bottom, update manager started to check for update automatically again and I saw this message:"the software on this computer is up to date. Last checked 2 seconds ago."

Kubuntu 12.04

Comment: This worked for me, and no other solution posted here worked. Except I don't have the Ubuntu UI (running command-line only under WSL), So instead, for each package `<pkg>` where the error occurred, I ran `sudo apt-get install <pkg>'. I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this just stops the updates for that specific software altogether. This is hardly a solution, is it?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and solved it by opening theh application "Software & Updates" and, in "Ubuntu Software" tab, changing the value of "Download from" (in that drop-down list, try to select, for example, Main Server if it was not like that).

Comment: Yes, only thing that worked for me. Switzerland server seems broken.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Linux inside VirtualBox on Windows and have Hyper-V (or WSL 2, which uses Hyper-V) enabled at the same time, you're in for a world of pain. This being one symptom. VirtualBox 6.1 says on the tin that it supports Hyper-V but it just isn't true (as of 2020-08-25 windows v2040 at least). Disable Hyper-V and you're golden. From [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35812945/345716):

In an *elevated* Command Prompt write this :

To disable:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

To enable:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

restart to take effect

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and all solutions provided using the terminal did not help.

For me, it was by going into:

Settings → Software & Updates → Other software: Uncheck all the boxes and press close.

It starts reloading the repos and updating. When I enter:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After that, there was no problem at all. I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: This does work yet it effectively blinds the machine from being able to install packages not part of the core build (until those checkboxes are re-activated later) ... yet necessary at times just to achieve an error free apt-get update which enables install of targeted packages

Answer (score 1):

As follow @robie-basak, I used `apt-cacher-ng` as mirror caching. So I Remove the proxy and the problem solved.

I remove the proxy in file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy`:

```
#Acquire::http::Proxy "http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:4321";
```

Then need to:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

I had just recently install Ubuntu 17.10 and was getting the same error of Hash Sum Mismatch for a some repository.I went to Software and Checked Source as shown below and there were no problems further for downloading repository from the terminal.

[image: My Software and Update Section]

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved all the packages not being installed by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install PACKAGENAME
```

For each of the packages. They are now installed and the "Hash Sum mismatch" error has gone.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you're running a router with parental controls, and havent put your raspberry pi into an "unmanaged" list. For me, I could see the url was redirecting to a circle domain, managed by the router.

So I just added my pi to the unmanaged list, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me. After trying and the suggested solutions, finally, I had downloaded the broken packages manually, copied them into /var/cache/apt/archives and removed the broken packages from /var/cache/apt/archives/partial.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in my Ubuntu 18.04, below is my practical experience:

1. Remove the proxy in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`
2. Change to official apt sources.list `/etc/apt/sources.list`
3. Run `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`
4. Clean packages `sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean -y`
5. Update and Upgrade.
   `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean -y`

Done!

Answer (score 0):

This happened for me on Ubuntu 16.04, and none of the top voted solutions worked. The solution was upgrading packages:

```
sudo apt-get update    # this will fail
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update    # this will succeed
```

Not sure if cleaning old lists (`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and/or `sudo apt-get clean`) helped or not! Use them if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

20190112 #Errors #apt #Fix #Updates Failed to fetch ... Hash Sum mismatch

1. Run apt-get and find out what key words to search for in `/etc/apt`:

   - $ sudo apt-get -y update
   - ...
   - Err:77 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
   - Hash Sum mismatch
   - ...
   - In this case, the keyword is "DEP-11"
2. Search the `/etc/apt` tree for the keyword(s):

   - $ sudo find /etc/apt -type f -exec egrep -in "DEP-11" "{}" /dev/null ";"
   - /apt.conf.d/50appstream:1:## This file is provided by appstreamcli(1) to download DEP-11
   - /apt.conf.d/50appstream:6:        deb::DEP-11  {
   - /apt.conf.d/50appstream:9:                Description "$(RELEASE)/$(COMPONENT) $(NATIVE_ARCHITECTURE) DEP-11 Metadata";
   - /apt.conf.d/50appstream:15:        # Normal-sized icons for GUI components described in the DEP-11
   - /apt.conf.d/50appstream:17:        deb::DEP-11-icons  {
   - /apt.conf.d/50appstream:20:                Description "$(RELEASE)/$(COMPONENT) DEP-11 64x64 Icons";
   - /apt.conf.d/50appstream:27:        # the DEP-11 YAML metadata.
   - /apt.conf.d/50appstream:28:        deb::DEP-11-icons-hidpi    {
   - /apt.conf.d/50appstream:31:                Description "$(RELEASE)/$(COMPONENT) DEP-11 128x128 Icons";
3. Having found the offending list, move it somewhere just in case this doesn't work:

   ```
   sudo mv -f /apt.conf.d/50appstream /tmp
   ```
4. Clean up `/var/lib/apt`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get -y clean  
   sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*  
   sudo find /var/lib/apt -type d -name "partial" -exec rm -rf "{}" ";"
   ```
5. Try to update now, it should work now:

   ```
   sudo apt-get -y update
   ```