# After apt-mirror

Tags: package-management, apt-mirror

I'm downloading packages with `sudo apt-mirror`. What should I do next to set packages being installed from the downloaded packages? I can't even see where are the packages downloaded by default. I looked at `/var/cache/apt/archives` but it seems there aren't downloaded to this place.

Can I interrupt `apt-mirror` command and continue tommorrow where it was interrupted?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can interrupt it ( apt-mirror ). Packages are saved on location specified in config file, /etc/apt/mirror.list. Then, to use files downloaded, you need to edit /etc/apt/sources.list ( or possibly add new file to sources.list.d directory ), i found nice how to on this blog :

http://popey.com/blog/2006/10/24/Creating_an_Ubuntu_repository_mirror_with_apt-mirror/

Answer (score 0):

**Apt-mirror**

```
sudo apt install apt-mirror
```

**Create a Source list**

```
sudo su

#Remove wrong ones from the configure file
sed -i '17,27d'  /etc/apt/mirror.list

#Insert correct ones
echo "
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
" >> /etc/apt/mirror.list
```

**Start Mirroring**

```
apt-mirror
```

**Location of packages:**

```
/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

**Add to apt sources list**

```
sudo su
echo "deb file:/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list


sudo apt-get update
```

**Apt-get fails with failed to fetch Packages.xz Hash Sum mismatch**

[apt-get hash sum mismatch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788173/apt-get-hash-sum-mismatch)

[Can't install software using apt-get install : hash sum mismatch and failed to fetch errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887076/cant-install-software-using-apt-get-install-hash-sum-mismatch-and-failed-to-f)

[Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://%20https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[update-manager "failed to download package files" but apt upgrade works](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160363/update-manager-failed-to-download-package-files-but-apt-upgrade-works)

**File not found - /var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar (2: No such file or directory)**

[kubuntu 18.04 apt-get update fails with missing icon @2 files](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2413921)

[Apt Mirror not mirroring bionic/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons](https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/issues/102)

```
wget https://mirror.cs.jmu.edu/pub/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/universe/dep11/ -r -np
```