# apt-get hash sum mismatch

Tags: apt, package-management

I am trying to install packages from an internal repository and I am getting persistent issues with hash sum mismatches on **ubuntu 14.04**.

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  xtd-driver
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Get:1 https://dsl.melexis.com/artifactory/debian-local xtd_prod/main amd64 xtd-driver amd64 1.2.11169 [31.7 kB]
99% [1 xtd-driver 15.7 kB/31.7 kB 50%]201 URI Done: https://dsl.melexis.com/artifactory/debian-local/pool/xtd_prod/xtd-driver/xtd-driver_1.2.11169_amd64.deb
ReceivedHash:
    - SHA512:dde5e268d592a35bca3016c11d9a2fc0caf9e4162f3efdbede3ce777868d9d89d11d9a03b5d7d48298407aaf9635881d16ba0fa3881cd126721b5059674cf392
    - SHA256:fbccb29880e1db835987f65cd59e5579ddf9b555d30799a0cdfdf1e0d6bd8643
    - SHA1:5c9517fd3cb985cd3806b0e0150fed20a16952e4
    - MD5Sum:552a59af64082cf6179706d0289cd15b
    - Checksum-FileSize:31706
ExpectedHash:
    - SHA1:5c9517fd3cb985cd3806b0e0150fed20a16952e4

Err:1 https://dsl.melexis.com/artifactory/debian-local xtd_prod/main amd64 xtd-driver amd64 1.2.11169
  Hash Sum mismatch
Fetched 31.7 kB in 0s (102 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch https://dsl.melexis.com/artifactory/debian-local/pool/xtd_prod/xtd-driver/xtd-driver_1.2.11169_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
root@5a1f77406773:/var/cache/apt/archives/partial# vi /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean
root@5a1f77406773:/var/cache/apt/archives/partial#
```

I see here that the expected hash is the same as the received *hash*, so why is doesn't `apt-get` accept this hash?

Is there some setting which needs tweaking?

Here is the complete output with some Apt debugging enabled:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  binutils cpp cpp-5 gcc gcc-5 libasan2 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libgcc-5-dev libgomp1 libisl15 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpc3 libmpfr4 libmpx0 libquadmath0 libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-headers-4.4.0-24 linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic
  linux-headers-generic linux-libc-dev manpages manpages-dev
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc cpp-doc gcc-5-locales gcc-multilib make autoconf automake libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc gcc-5-multilib gcc-5-doc libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan2-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libubsan0-dbg libcilkrts5-dbg libmpx0-dbg
  libquadmath0-dbg glibc-doc man-browser
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils cpp cpp-5 gcc gcc-5 libasan2 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libgcc-5-dev libgomp1 libisl15 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpc3 libmpfr4 libmpx0 libquadmath0 libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-headers-4.4.0-24 linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic
  linux-headers-generic linux-libc-dev manpages manpages-dev xtd-driver
0 upgraded, 29 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: https://dsl.melexis.com/artifactory/debian-local xtd_prod/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dsl.melexis.com_artifactory_debian-local_dists_xtd%5fprod_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=0)
Need to get 31.7 kB/39.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 180 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  xtd-driver
Install these packages without verification? [y/N]
E: Some packages could not be authenticated
root@5a1f77406773:/var/cache/apt/archives/partial# apt-get install xtd-driver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  binutils cpp cpp-5 gcc gcc-5 libasan2 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libgcc-5-dev libgomp1 libisl15 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpc3 libmpfr4 libmpx0 libquadmath0 libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-headers-4.4.0-24 linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic


  linux-headers-generic linux-libc-dev manpages manpages-dev
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc cpp-doc gcc-5-locales gcc-multilib make autoconf automake libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc gcc-5-multilib gcc-5-doc libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan2-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libubsan0-dbg libcilkrts5-dbg libmpx0-dbg
  libquadmath0-dbg glibc-doc man-browser
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils cpp cpp-5 gcc gcc-5 libasan2 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libgcc-5-dev libgomp1 libisl15 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpc3 libmpfr4 libmpx0 libquadmath0 libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-headers-4.4.0-24 linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic
  linux-headers-generic linux-libc-dev manpages manpages-dev xtd-driver
0 upgraded, 29 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=1)
Checking index: https://dsl.melexis.com/artifactory/debian-local xtd_prod/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dsl.melexis.com_artifactory_debian-local_dists_xtd%5fprod_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4)(Trusted=0)
Need to get 31.7 kB/39.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 180 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  xtd-driver
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Get:1 https://dsl.melexis.com/artifactory/debian-local xtd_prod/main amd64 xtd-driver amd64 1.2.11169 [31.7 kB]
99% [1 xtd-driver 15.7 kB/31.7 kB 50%]201 URI Done: https://dsl.melexis.com/artifactory/debian-local/pool/xtd_prod/xtd-driver/xtd-driver_1.2.11169_amd64.deb
ReceivedHash:
    - SHA512:dde5e268d592a35bca3016c11d9a2fc0caf9e4162f3efdbede3ce777868d9d89d11d9a03b5d7d48298407aaf9635881d16ba0fa3881cd126721b5059674cf392
    - SHA256:fbccb29880e1db835987f65cd59e5579ddf9b555d30799a0cdfdf1e0d6bd8643
    - SHA1:5c9517fd3cb985cd3806b0e0150fed20a16952e4
    - MD5Sum:552a59af64082cf6179706d0289cd15b
    - Checksum-FileSize:31706
ExpectedHash:
    - SHA1:5c9517fd3cb985cd3806b0e0150fed20a16952e4

Err:1 https://dsl.melexis.com/artifactory/debian-local xtd_prod/main amd64 xtd-driver amd64 1.2.11169
  Hash Sum mismatch
Fetched 31.7 kB in 0s (102 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch https://dsl.melexis.com/artifactory/debian-local/pool/xtd_prod/xtd-driver/xtd-driver_1.2.11169_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: @anx I added the complete output to the question.

Comment: @anx Ow, you're right. I am using the xenial release which disabled SHA-1 checksums, so the checksum's can't be validated, because the MD5 and SHA-1 are not accepted. And apparently this results in a confusing error down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to avoid people having to scan the comments, the reason was that newer distros like Ubuntu Xenial no longer accept SHA-1 (or MD-5 for that matter) as they are no longer considered secure.