# How to Download entire Ubuntu Software Repository in to the cache for easy offline use when no internet connection

Tags: apt, cache

How to fill apt-cache of all programs. 
**Download the entire Ubuntu Software center into apt cache for offline use.**

```
sudo apt-get install --download-only *
```

- **Deb files**.
- **Size Don't Matter**
- **Binary 64x deb package (amd64), of the programs for LTS release Jammy Jellyfish is enough**

How to Download entire Ubuntu Software Repository of programs, in to apt cache, for easy offline use when no internet connection is available ?

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives/
ls
```

this list the packages. I would like to fill this up with every program there is. The entire software archive.

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install --download-only *
```

That should of done it.

An example is osdisk.com. It had 10 DVDs with the program deb files on it that gets copied in to the cache from the DVDs, ready for possibly installing one day or not.

**Download the entire Ubuntu Software center into apt cache for offline use**

Keryx the accepted answer is not the answer am after. Nor is APToncd. [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)
[image: Keryx]

Working, easy and explainable is also part of the answer, Entirely explainable by the answerer and the entire software achieve not a couple of selected programs.

**Last time: This would be the function i require**

```
sudo apt-get install --download-only *
```

Comment: Are you sure you want it all, even for a single architecture & a single release you're looking at >450GB if you include source packages too.. more if you want multiple architectures, multiple releases etc... though less if you limit yourself to binary only.  That's a rather large download!  Are you sure you want it all

Comment: Also the info may be different tomorrow as updates occur all the time.

Comment: That's >450GB for the whole archive with source *enabled*, my size did not include every package version but only the *latest* version of each package in the archive at a single *moment* in time...  (*I did assume the four main repositories as found in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu ie. main, universe, restricted, multiverse*) ...

Comment: If NO source is included; you're looking at closer to 70GB  (*which still isn't small! and sizes of course will vary on release, architecture etc*)

Comment: apt-mirror is the tool to use. `sudo apt-get install --download-only *` does -not- download all debs. The `*` is not a wildcard.  https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/apt-mirror.1.html   https://computingforgeeks.com/creating-ubuntu-mirrors-using-apt-mirror/

Comment: Apt-get hash sum mis match https://askubuntu.com/questions/788173/apt-get-hash-sum-mismatch

Comment: Apt-mirror will not include Dep11 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252828/apt-mirror-for-amd64-did-not-include-focal-main-dep11-and-focal-main-cnf-command

Comment: 2016, apt-mirror does not reflect dep11/Components-* and dep11/icons-*  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-mirror/+bug/1550852

Answer (score 4):

**Apt-mirror**

```
sudo apt install apt-mirror
```

**Create a Source list**

```
sudo su

# Remove wrong ones from the configure file
sed -i '17,27d'  /etc/apt/mirror.list

# Insert correct ones
echo "
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
" >> /etc/apt/mirror.list
```

**Start Mirroring**

```
apt-mirror
```

[Apt-mirror has finished downloading the archive.
What now! where from here to use for offline installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1463556/apt-mirror-has-finished-downloading-the-archive-what-now-where-from-here-to-us/1463567#1463567)