# Apt-mirror has finished downloading the archive. What now! where from here to use for offline installation?

Tags: apt, package-management, archive

Apt-mirror has finished downloading the archive.

Where do I go from here for an offline installation?

Apt-mirror:

```
sudo apt install apt-mirror
```

Create a Source list:

```
sudo su
```

Remove wrong ones from the configure file:

```
sed -i '17,27d'  /etc/apt/mirror.list
```

Insert correct ones:

```
echo "
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
" >> /etc/apt/mirror.list
```

Start Mirroring:

```
apt-mirror
```

Comment: It's very difficult to figure out what you are asking. Invest some time and explain what you are trying to do and what didn't work. I have a working local mirror, but I don't know what you want to ask.

Comment: Once install apt-mirror, where from there, to get it working.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the complete listing of your mirror.list file, not the commands you used to create it. Also show the complete listing of your sources.list file, not the commands you used to create it. Also the postmirror.sh file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Location of packages:**

```
/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

**Add to apt sources list:**

```
sudo su
echo "deb file:/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list


sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Apt-get hash sum mis match https://askubuntu.com/questions/788173/apt-get-hash-sum-mismatch

Comment: Apt-mirror will not include Dep11 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252828/apt-mirror-for-amd64-did-not-include-focal-main-dep11-and-focal-main-cnf-command

Comment: apt-mirror does not reflect dep11/Components-* and dep11/icons-* https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-mirror/+bug/1550852