# Can't install software using apt-get install : hash sum mismatch and failed to fetch errors

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, cmake

I have a Ubuntu 16.10 64 bit machine.

When I try to do `sudo apt-get install cmake`, I get the following error:

```
After this operation, 20.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 cmake amd64 3.5.2-2ubuntu1 [2,779 kB]
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 cmake amd64 3.5.2-2ubuntu1
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:28f7a54d94e32027321460169ddf7c66d627e96a275612e371064192b4f1fe75
   - SHA1:be57190df55b20ddfc192570cd225436fa60caf0 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:454e05c9e6ae224d3416b04f2a876699 [weak]
   - Checksum-FileSize:2778872 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:d3981d14c6c2d2d0c42cc7dd00b42264e5e94f7bb2d5908ae3bbcc707e8a881b
   - SHA1:9c2716a4ff17005f7a9f4c9b6cf9c370a5a813ef [weak]
   - MD5Sum:9118651936fd4509d1dd98b662678ac6 [weak]
   - Checksum-FileSize:2778872 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Wed, 29 Jun 2016 15:10:18 +0000
Fetched 2,779 kB in 7min 48s (5,926 B/s)                                       
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cmake/cmake_3.5.2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:28f7a54d94e32027321460169ddf7c66d627e96a275612e371064192b4f1fe75
    - SHA1:be57190df55b20ddfc192570cd225436fa60caf0 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:454e05c9e6ae224d3416b04f2a876699 [weak]
    - Checksum-FileSize:2778872 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:d3981d14c6c2d2d0c42cc7dd00b42264e5e94f7bb2d5908ae3bbcc707e8a881b
    - SHA1:9c2716a4ff17005f7a9f4c9b6cf9c370a5a813ef [weak]
    - MD5Sum:9118651936fd4509d1dd98b662678ac6 [weak]
    - Checksum-FileSize:2778872 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Wed, 29 Jun 2016 15:10:18 +0000
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I get the following error.

```
#lot of lines like the next two lines
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [4,653 B]
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/multiverse Translation-en [2,076 B]
Fetched 816 kB in 23min 40s (574 B/s)                                          
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety-updates/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_yakkety-updates_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety-updates/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.gz  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can anyone kindly point me to a solution for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: The sudo apt-get update error is normal it just means that there is a small error that just prints out those messages, and for cmake did you try downloading and installing manually. http://www.cmake.org/download/ for more info for how to do that http://askubuntu.com/questions/355565/how-to-install-latest-cmake-version-in-linux-ubuntu-from-command-line

Comment: @Peyto The OP would do better to fix his repository than to risk further conflict by trying manual installations.

Comment: Will you edit your question and append the output of this command: `egrep -v "^#|^$" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*;egrep -v "^#|^$" /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu 16.04, why do you have yakkety repositories in your sources?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
sudo apt-get -o 'Acquire::http::No-Cache=true; Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth=0;' install NAMEHERE
```

apt bug explained here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=810796

Answer (score 1):

From **system settings** select **software & updates**. It will take some time for update your OS from server for India, after system update done  try to install software what you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove the repository entry causing the problem.**

The problems you are having is a result of installing a repository ahead of your Ubuntu version.  This causing the unmet dependencies breackage you are seeing.

The resolution is to remove the offending repository entry.  You can identify this by the **yakkety** reference in your error message:

```
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 cmake amd64 3.5.2-2ubuntu1
```

Remove that entry, then update your repository cache with:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

If you need to install something that is made for a newer OS release, you will have to manually compile it and it's neccesary dependencies.

Alternatively you can look for a PPA that is made for your Ubuntu installion, which you have indicated as Ubuntu 16.04.