# update-manager "failed to download package files" but apt upgrade works

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

I have some strange issue here. Update Manager and Synaptic are not able to download packages, but apt has no problem at all.

Update Manager says exactly «Failed to download package files».

I already changed server and cleaned /var/lib/apt/lists/: every time, apt works like a charm, but GUI softwares don't.

I can continue using the command line, but I'd like to understand why this is happening.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**: Synaptic says:

> W: Failed to fetch http://pkg.adfinis-sygroup.ch/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/libmysqlclient20_5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
>
> Could not open file /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/libmysqlclient20_5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb - open (2: No such file or directory) [IP: 2001:618:1:129::165 80]

This is repeated for every package to download.

If I try to remove the /var/cache/apt/archives directory I get `rm: cannot remove '/var/cache/apt/archives/': Device or resource busy`

When I run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` I don't get any errors. Updates get installed correctly. That's what I meant by saying that «apt has no problem at all».

**UPDATE**: I applied some updates with `apt-get` forcing IPv4, and everything went smoothly. `update-manager` still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the errors you get ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I update the question. The error message was the one in the question title. I will update again if Synaptic gives more info.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and add any error output to the question.

Comment: Thank you @N0rbert for your comment. I updated the question with more details. As stated before, apt gives no problem.

Comment: @abePdIta Do you remember which protocol `apt` / `apt-get` used - IPv4 or IPv6? Do you have any problems with IPv6 resolution in other applications?

Comment: Hi @N0rbert. How do I know which one it's using? In apt-get output I see only domain names. When I issue `ping pkg.adfinis-sygroup.ch` it uses IPv6 (by the way, no problem pinging), but I'm not sure about apt-get.
I have no problem with other applications, but again I'm not sure which version of the IP they're using.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try to force APT to use IPv4 and compare the results :) See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100887/57134 . If it fails then remove the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As N0rbert suggested in comments, IPv4 was the thing.

In the question he linked (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100887/57134) there are instruction to make `apt-get` use IPv4 by default. This also affected update-manager and the problem has been solved.

Thanks N0rbert for the help!