# How do I fix a "Hash sum mismatch" error?

Tags: installation, upgrade, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [Trouble downloading updates due to “Hash sum mismatch” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-updates-due-to-hash-sum-mismatch-error)

I'm trying to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 using the Update Manager. I keep getting the following error:-

> Could not download the upgrades
>
> The upgrade has aborted. Please check your Internet connection or installation 
>     media and try again. All files downloaded so far have been kept.
>
> Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator- datetime/indicator-datetime_0.3.94-0ubuntu2_i386.deb Hash Sum mismatch

I have tried rerunning the update manager a number of times and I always get the same error. A reboot had no effect. Any ideas on how to fix?