# `apt-get upgrade` fails intermittantly with "Hash Sum mismatch", and must be rerun

Tags: apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [Trouble downloading updates due to “Hash sum mismatch” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-updates-due-to-hash-sum-mismatch-error)

A number of times recently over the last few months when I try and apt-get update & apt-get dist-upgrade I get the following error while apt is downloading a package...

```
Failed to fetch http://foo/bar.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Upon getting this error I rerun upgrade immediately and it will usually progress until another package with the same error.  After rerunning upgrade a few times everything completes successfully.

The errors occur with multiple different package sites including the official ubuntu ones.  I haven't had any problems with my Internet connection or wget otherwise.