# apt-get update failed to fetch server

Tags: apt, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trouble downloading updates due to “Hash sum mismatch” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-updates-due-to-hash-sum-mismatch-error)

Everytime when I do `sudo apt-get update`, i get always this error:

```
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en     
Fetched 2,141 kB in 8s (255 kB/s)                                              
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_binary-amd64_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'm running ubuntu server 12.04 LTS.