# which are the different ways i can update software catalog?

Tags: software-center

while facing problem(s) with software center 5.2.6 on ubuntu 12.04, i reinstalled the software center and executed following command on gnome terminal
`$ sudo dpkg --configure -a`

```
Setting up software-center (5.2.6) ... Updating software catalog...**this may take a moment.**
```

However there is no or little beyond this point.

**Is there any other way to update software catalog?** 
because every other time i open up software center it keeps on crashing.

Answer (score -1):

What about this script [which solves Hash sum mismatches](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-updates-due-to-hash-sum-mismatch-error) too :

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo rm -rfv /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```