# Why do I get "Failed to fetch [...] Hash Sum mismatch" errors during update?

Tags: 12.04, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trouble downloading updates due to “Hash sum mismatch” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-updates-due-to-hash-sum-mismatch-error)

Every time I try to update my system I get these messages:

```
W:Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_universe_binary-amd64_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I don't understand what this message is about or what the problem is.

Answer (score 15):

I solved using these commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```