# I Can't Update My Ubuntu? What's the Solution?

Tags: 12.04, updates, 64-bit

Dear Ubuntu Users,
       Hello. The problem that im having, is updating my system of Ubuntu, you know security updates and ppa's. I check for updates and do have a secure connection, but I unexpectedly get message saying,

```
W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_universe_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_universe_binary-amd64_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I go to the directory the `var/lib/apt/lists/parital`

Here is the image of the directory/file system

[image: ![]FileDirectoryIssue.png

I went to the directory and I found all the files failed, but two of them are not failed.
Have you had this problem, what was your solution toward this problem. I keep my system up to date with upgrades, a die hard Linux User. If you have any recommendations, I would apperciate it!
Thank You! System Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble downloading updates due to “Hash sum mismatch” error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-updates-due-to-hash-sum-mismatch-error)

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean 
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo rm -fR /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

Also see the answer of Jorge Castro [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-updates-due-to-hash-sum-mismatch-error)