# Set apt-get to use gzip bz2, gzip or uncompressed file?

Tags: apt, updates, software-installation

The ubuntu repositories dists folder contains both Packages, Packages.gz and Packages.bz2 files. Out of these, apt-get uses one of them during an update. Where can I configure apt to choose a particular compression type file instead of others.

I am in a university using an internal mirror and for some reason one of the files is giving a `Hash mismatch error`. I think if I use bz2 instead of gzip, perhaps I can get past the erroneous file. My `apt-get update` always tries to fetch .gz files and fails on one of them.

Comment: It is very unlikely that this will solve your error. What repository are you using?

Comment: I am using internal mirror for trusty packages. Hash mismatch for `ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-i386_Packages`. Anyways, I am more interested in apt than solving the error, hence the title. [Answers to this error](http://askubuntu.com/q/41605/)  is delete the local file and update again. I did that only to repeat the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, you can try this apt option:

```
sudo apt-get -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=bz2 update
```

See the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/apt.conf.5.html) for apt.conf.

But I'm pretty sure that your problem comes from the repository itself.