# squid interfering with apt-get?

Tags: apt, updates, squid

I recently installed squid along with Dan's Guardian. Ever since I got them up and running I've been getting errors when I try to run apt-get update. The errors look like this: 
`W: Failed to fetch 
gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_restricted_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_multiverse_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_restricted_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_restricted_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_universe_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_multiverse_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch`

I run ubuntu 14.04. Anybody have an idea how to fix this?
`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-updates-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found someting similair, running this code did it or me:
`export {http_proxy,https_proxy,ftp_proxy}="http://127.0.0.1:3128"`

Answer (score 0):

So do you still has direct Internet connection, or through Squid only? Apt-get needs to be configured to work through proxy, as well as any other software. In /etc/apt/apt.conf add

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "MYDOMAIN\MYNAME:MYPASS@MY.PROXY.COM:MYPORT"
```