# Installing FOG on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, apt, mysql, fog

I am trying to install FOG on Ubuntu 12.04 Server.

I have downloaded the latest version from SF, but when I try to install it, it fails when trying to install MySQL, specifically with:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to manually apt-get mysql-server-5.5, but that fails, citing the following dependencies:

```
Depends: mysql-client-5.5 (>=5.5.38-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)  but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libdbi-perl  but it is not going to be installed
Depends: mysql-server-core-5.5 (>=5.5.38-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)  but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libhtml-template-perl but it is not going to be installed
```

Long story short, is this just a big incompatibility with 12.04 and the newest MySQL builds or something more fundamental? I'm guessing in the former case, it's possible to alter the FOG install script to grab an older version, but I don't have a clue where to start with that.

I'm on 12.04 because that is the last LTS release suggested for FOG (They warn against 14.04 [here](http://www.fogproject.org/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_14.04)).

I've checked all my sources and they're the correct ones for precise pangolin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, following advice from [Trouble downloading updates due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-updates-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error), I cleared out APT's lists and re-synced it. Everything fine now.

Just remove the content of /var/lib/apt/lists directory:

```
sudo rm -fR /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Good work man but it is good to include at least a copy/paste of the actual answer for others with this issue, I already edited it for you it will get approved shortly.