# Failed to fetch update on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates

While running the update at Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr). The following error is being encountered:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

command used:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Enter the following commands in a Terminal:

```
sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: +1 for me. However, it would be great if you could comment why this issue happens.

Comment: +1 what is the root cause?

Comment: see this answer for the root cause: http://askubuntu.com/a/160179/66329 -- TLDR: due to race conditions, your local repo cache can get into an inconsistent state; so delete it and `apt-get update` will refresh the whole thing from source

Comment: after that i got "Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch"

Comment: If you still get the other error, remove everything from the partials directory `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partials/* -vf

Comment: A  "-r" should probably be added to the rm command. I had to remove the contents of the "partial" directory to get the repositories back into a stable state.

Comment: I too got the "Hash Sum mismatch" error, and neither of the solutions have worked.

Comment: I fixed it using sudo apt-get clean;
sudo apt-get update

Comment: I also continued to receive the Hash sum mismatch at first attempt, removing partials helped thanks!

Comment: I had this problem and found that I had to run the solution on my **mirror**, not my local client that was using the mirror. Then just run `sudo apt-mirror` as usual afterwards to update the mirror and wait for it to finish.

Comment: None of these work for me. My apt-get remains a clusterfuck and it all started one day without any tinkering to trigger it.

Comment: @ClaytonDukes After `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf`, I repeated `sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get update` several times, then finally this issue is fixed.