# ubuntu update failed from 14.04 lts. failed to fetch something

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, updates

this is not the same case as
[Failed to fetch update on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553765/failed-to-fetch-update-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr)

the error is:

```
    Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 

W:Failed to fetch 
http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/Release Unable to find 
expected entry 'main/binary-amd-64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong 
sources.list entry or malformed file) 
, W:Failed to fetch 
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/Release Unable to find 
expected entry 'main/binary-amd-64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong 
sources.list entry or malformed file) 
, W:Failed to fetch 
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/Release Unable 
to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd-64/Packages' in Release file 
(Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file) 
, W:Failed to fetch 
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/Release 
Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd-64/Packages' in 
Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file) 
, W:Failed to fetch 
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/Release Unable 
to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd-64/Packages' in Release file 
(Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file) 
, W:Failed to fetch 
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-proposed/Release Unable 
to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd-64/Packages' in Release file 
(Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file) 
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or 
old ones used instead. 


Restoring original system state
```

command used is:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

**[Updated]**
on pinging

```
ping archive.ubuntu.com
```

the output was:

```
64 bytes from obake.canonical.com (91.189.92.200): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=294 ms
64 bytes from obake.canonical.com (91.189.92.200): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=295 ms
64 bytes from obake.canonical.com (91.189.92.200): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=295 ms
```

....... until i stopped it.

also the system ***settings->details*** shows that this is 14.04LTS

output of:

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

is  `amd64`

i opened `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and there is no mention of utopic. everywhere  it is trusty.

**[Update - 2]** 
i checked the above links and there is indeed no entry of `main/binary-amd-64/Packages` but everywhere it is `main/binary-amd64/Packages` (notice the hyphen between amd and 64).

i used the command:

```
grep -r "amd-64" /etc/apt
```

and got no output.

Comment: Have you checked your network connection as suggested?  Try this: ping archive.ubuntu.com

Comment: First, Utopic is not 14.04lts, it's 14.10. Second, have you tried another mirror?

Comment: As you say you're on 14.04 (Trusty) and not 14.10 (Utopic), open `/etc/apt/sources.list` and wherever you find the word `utopic`, replace it with `trusty`!

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg --print-architecture`?

Answer (score 0):

Backup you `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and comment out all files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder.
Than use the following `sources.list` to upgrade:

```
deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe restricted multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main universe restricted multiverse

deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main universe restricted multiverse
```

Comment: how would I do this? do I have to comment out all the lines in all the files of '/etc/apt/sources.list.d' manually ?

Comment: or, if you prefer, move them all temporarly in another folder...