# Unable to install Linux container in 14.04 LTS

Tags: apt, software-installation

Firstly I tried to update Linux with the command :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It failed with errors and I resolved it with command :

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

Which was mentioned in the answers to [Failed to fetch update on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553765/failed-to-fetch-update-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr), and then it displayed this :

```
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial': is a directory
```

After that I tried using commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It came with the same error as mentioned in [Failed to fetch update on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553765/failed-to-fetch-update-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr).

And neither can I now install `lxc`.

Comment: sudo apt-get clean deletes (cleans) the contents of those directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

will delete the contents of those directories.

Then, try the command again:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If you continue to get the error, change mirrors and repeat the process over again.

---

Alternatively, you can run this instead:

```
sudo rm -R /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

The -R flag is recursive so it will delete directories as well as files.