# apt-get upgrade fails with "failed to fetch - hash sum mismatch" on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, upgrade

I am trying to update software for my 14.04 version using

```
apt-get update 
apt-get upgrade
```

But I get this error

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6-dbg_2.19-0ubuntu6.13_amd64.deb
Hash Sum mismatch
```

So, I manually downloaded this file

```
libc6-dbg_2.19-0ubuntu6.13_amd64.deb
```

And tried to install but could not install due to bad quality.

Following the questions below didn't help.

- [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)
- [Failed to fetch update on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553765/failed-to-fetch-update-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr)

Comment: Please ask one question per post

Comment: The first thing you do prior to an update is backup as there are no guarantees you will not have a problem. To upgrade see - https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html

Comment: As a Fedora guy, I find Windows difficult. Nothing in the new micorosft office menues are in any way intuitive and it takes multiple steps to save . I dont even see a print button ... The error messages in Windows are cryptic at best and the code is closed source so I can not fix anything. Windows is way harder then Linux, you just need to learn a new os, takes time

Comment: @DavidFoerster, steeldriver Thanks for correcting me.. I have edited question

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Thanks!. I really missed that. Yes you are correct. We are good at our comfort zone. Anything new will take time to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you started working with Linux back when Slackware was cutting edge, you'd consider today's Ubuntu to be a dream to work with.  That and the package you are trying to install is a debian package....  supported by Ubuntu but not Ubunbtu software.

If stability and relatively error free operation is your goal, you should not be installing or upgrading pre-released updates.  Pre-release is, by definition not thoroughly tested and could very well have bugs.  Some serious.

Off the top it looks like the package you are trying to install is corrupted so the error message you are seeing is the system protecting itself from installing a "bad" package.

If this is a package that you really need and want, a first step after downloading it would be to run a checksum against it to make sure that it is a legit package and that the file is not corrupted.  There are lots of threads here that explain in depth how to do this.

If you don't actually need this package and especially if this package is a pre-release, you are probably better off NOT trying to install it.

Comment: How did you arrive at this conclusion? I checked my 14.04.5 box and `2.19-0ubuntu6.13` seems to be the default libc6-dbg package version from `trusty-updates`

Comment: @steeldriver -- are you updating from trusty or to trusty? sorry I don't remember the version code names.

Comment: The OP complained that Ubuntu was not as easy to manage as Microsoft.  I saw that he had pre-release, proposed updates enabled.  This is inconsistent with OP's desire for an error and  trouble environment.  That was what I was responding to.  I didn't run a checksum on the package but I'm guessing it wouldn't match.

Comment: @Jones...Thanks for your suggestion. I will try and post the results

Comment: @jones0610 I am not sure if that is important.  I am new to ubuntu. I have checked important security updates from other software tab.