# How to resolve hash sum mismatch -- solution provided here does NOT work!

Tags: software-sources

I have struggled for hours on end to fix a serious problem which started after the turn of the year. I *cannot* make Synaptic reload! I have read through the questions here as well as the answers. I have TRIED THEM ALL!

I am *no novice* to Linux! I started out with a half page of errors -- I've reduced it to ONE error that I cannot fix...

```
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I do not have the above link *anywhere* in my system that I can find! "dists" or "binary" is simply not in my lists!

Below is a copy of my software sources list. Where does the above link come from?!

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```

Comment: It's normal that you don't have "dists" or "binary" in your sources.list. APT adds them by itself to the lines in your sources.list in order to build the URL to fetch the packages lists. Your problem lies elsewhere. It would be helpful if you explained what you tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED!!!!

/var/lib/apt -- This was the real source of the problem. This was also where I actually located the mysterious files that kept showing up in the errors.

The first step is to MANUALLY delete the*partial* folder. However, here is where something really weird happened. I opened the 'partial' folder and saw right away the troublesome error file—but before I could do anything, the troublesome file along with all other files in that same folder, one at a time, simply VANISHED in front of my eyes! I had  a hunch at this point and without bothering the other files in the 'apt' folder I tried Synaptic again—it reloaded PERFECTLY! Then I systematically, one at a time, re-checked EVERYTHING in the repositories.

The moral of the story? Anytime you have BADSIG, Hash sum mismatch etc. the first thing you do is go to /etc/apt –open the lists with leafpad—wipe out everything! Replace this with a list made by Ubuntu repository creator.

NEXT go to /var/lib/apt, if there is a 'partial' folder DELETE it. If this does not work then COPY AND PASTE all other files in this folder to somewhere else, then delete all these files in the folder you just C&Pasted from—then—add them back one at a time till things work right.

DO NOT, I repeat, DO NOT attempt to delete these things using CLEAN or AUTOCLEAN or any such. MANUALLY DELETE these!!!!!

THE PROBLEM is in the CLEAN and AUTOCLEAN features of Linux-Lubuntu. There is a real GLITCH here!!!

I have 5 computers ALL with Lubuntu--ALL with exactly the same issue!!!

Comment: What is a partial folder?

Comment: It is present in /var/lib/apt

Answer (score 0):

run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Take a note of the ubuntu repositories which are giving the problem

Type in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install vim
cd /etc/apt
sudo vim sources.list
```

Identify those repositories and put a `#` in front of them to comment them out.

If they are non ubuntu repositories, do

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

Identify the problem repositories, then do

```
sudo mv repository-name.list repository-name.list.backup
sudo mv repository-name.list.save repository-name.list.save.backup
```

Remove the partial folder in /var/lib/apt

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/partial*
```

Now update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Go back to sources.list

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Uncomment the previously commented repositories by removing the `#` in front of them.

Go to sources.list.d and restore the backed up repositories

```
sudo mv repository-name.list.backup repository-name.list
sudo mv repository-name.list.save.backup repository.list.save
```

Do another update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Hopefully problems will now get resolved

If you get any gpg key error, note down the keys being asked for. It is a sixteen character combination of uppercase letters and numbers. Then type in terminal

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com `sixteen-character-key`
```

Again do

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Hopefully the problems would get resolved now.

If you want you can make the process easier by doing the following

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
sudo launchpad-getkeys
```

Have a happy experience with ubuntu