# archive.canonical.com repo for trusty is broken, how do I report the issue?

Tags: apt, bug-reporting, canonical

http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/

It seems that the repo has been updated about one hour ago (around 18:26), but the `InRelease` file is a few weeks old. This causes `apt-get` to fail with the following error:

```
Fetched 5,627 B in 2s (2,712 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/partner/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The same thing is happening for `binary-i386` and all other sections. Then entire repository is broken because of the old `InRelease` file. The `InRelease` file contains different sizes and checksums than the actual `Packages*` files have.

What's the proper way to report this to Canonical?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)

Comment: No, this a problem with the repo, not with the local index.

Comment: May I inquire why in the hell you are still using the Canonical servers?

Comment: It's installed by default on Google Cloud Engine, because it includes some custom Google packages.

Comment: All that I can suggest at the moment is trying to use the main servers

Comment: These packages do not exist on the main servers. This is the "partners" repo that only exists on archive.canonical.com.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30229/discussion-between-david-cole-and-lukas-lalinsky).

Answer (score 2):

Contact Canonical on http://www.canonical.com/services/contact-us

**Low quality queue reviewers:**  That's it!