# Ubuntu 14.04.3LTS 64-bit - apt-get update error , Hash Sum mismatch

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, software-center, update-manager

apt-get update error. The following links result in a Hash Sum mismatch. Scared of following any other answers because all of them seem to be unique for every person's chosen mirror.

Are these obsolete?
If they are how do I remove them?

```
W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

EDIT: Same problem occured when i completely removed ubuntu 14.04 and freshly installed ubuntu GNOME 14.04. Answer below.

Comment: here
https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error

Comment: @MikeSerchenya Tried the approved answer in your link. Same links failed again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok found a solution to my problem

in the file "/etc/apt/sources.list" i just commented out these two line:

```
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

it fixed the issue and now apt-get update finishes with no errors but i still don't know if this is the correct way of fixing this issue.

Comment: But this is not a solution. You have stopped updating from these sources and of course you shouldn't get error about it.!!!!