# Ubuntu 15.10 Fresh Installation Errors

Tags: 15.10

Just installed ubuntu 15.10 but as soon as I try to do `sudo apt-get update`, following error occurs:

```
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 977C43A8BA684223
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/main/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here is /etc/apt/sources.list

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 15.10 _Wily Werewolf_ - Release amd64 (20151021)]/ wily main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
```

Any help?

Comment: This error occurs when I run `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you got:

> W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org  Release: The following
>   signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not
>   available: NO_PUBKEY 977C43A8BA684223

Means you have to  add that missing key `977C43A8BA684223`  by  redownloading the keys first:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys
```

Then type:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 977C43A8BA684223 
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Why this happens?

Comment: Your message error happened because  you don't have a suitable public key for the repository you added.  So you need to retrieve the key from Ubuntu key server.

Comment: Now this is the error:


W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/main/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: @PleaseDeleteMeAfter executing your commands, these errors happen. Now Keys missing error do not happen anymore.

Comment: @PleaseDeleteMe This: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14957813/

Comment: @PleaseDeleteMe I have changed the server and instead of us.archive.ubuntu.com now I did just archive.ubuntu.com but still the same error. `Hash Sum Mismatch`

Comment: Ok. What if you remove those files in your `lists` directory then upgrade and update? (that is a *radical* solution but it works most of the time. `) It is same as this [solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error) @ssc

Comment: hahaha I don't know what exactly is wrong with Ubuntu 15.10 but seems like this issue is not going to resolve this way. Still same error @PleaseDeleteMe

Comment: @PleaseDeleteMe Are you in some ubuntu chat room? If yes, can I be the part of that room as well?

Comment: @PleaseDeleteMe I shutdown my machine last night and today when I started again, it was working. No idea what solved it but I hope it was one of your solution(s). Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing keys from the Ubuntu key server.  Try this:

```
# sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 977C43A8BA684223
```