# apt- sudo apt-get update not working!

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

Here is the error message after running sudo apt-get update (only the error part) :

```
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Edit: After following this solution : [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error) , I get this ( after Get:42 ...... line) :

```
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IN                 
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_IN           
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_IN           
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_IN             
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Fetched 2,981 kB in 3min 52s (12.8 kB/s)                                       
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/source/Sources  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/source/Sources  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/source/Sources  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

EDIT : after following GAD3R 's solution :

```
mohitgarg68@mohitgarg68-Inspiron-3542:~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://download.mono-project.com wheezy InRelease [8,036 B]
Get:2 http://download.mono-project.com wheezy/main amd64 Packages [56.6 kB]    
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]           
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease [15.5 kB]                      
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]          
Get:6 http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [72 B]                       
Get:7 http://download.mono-project.com wheezy/main i386 Packages [56.6 kB]     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:8 http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release [11.9 kB]                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [105 kB]         
Get:10 http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources [14 B]                     
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease [15.5 kB]                     
Get:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease [65.9 kB]       
Get:13 http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages [14 B]              
Get:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [933 B]                 
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [4,035 B] 
Get:16 http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages [14 B]               
Get:17 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [260 kB]       
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [33.0 kB]   
Get:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease [15.5 kB]                     
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [2,767 B] 
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [427 kB] 
Get:22 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [5,352 B]
Get:23 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [150 kB]   
Get:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease [15.5 kB]                     
Ign http://download.mono-project.com wheezy/main Translation-en_IN             
Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [13.0 kB]
Get:26 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [5,547 B]
Get:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease [15.4 kB]                     
Ign http://download.mono-project.com wheezy/main Translation-en                
Get:28 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [709 kB]
Get:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease [15.5 kB]                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IN                     
Get:30 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [123 kB]
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease [15.5 kB]                     
Get:32 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [15.9 kB]
Get:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages [2,547 B]           
Get:34 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [2,548 B]            
Get:35 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4,990 B]
Get:36 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [1,731 B]           
Get:37 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [399 kB]  
Get:38 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg [316 B]                     
Get:39 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [338 kB]
Get:40 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg [316 B]                     
Get:41 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages [20.5 kB]           
Get:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [20.4 kB]            
Get:43 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [12.7 kB]
Get:44 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [10.8 kB]           
Get:45 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [123 kB]
Get:46 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [13.2 kB]
Get:47 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [5,164 B]
Get:48 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [688 kB] 
Get:49 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages [2,129 B]           
Get:50 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en [234 kB] 
Get:51 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [2,129 B]            
Get:52 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [966 B]             
Get:53 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages [15.8 kB]           
Get:54 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en [2,570 B]
Get:55 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en [3,206 B]
Get:56 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [15.8 kB]            
Get:57 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en [72.5 kB]
Get:58 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [5,429 B]           
Get:59 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages [7,629 B]           
Get:60 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [7,640 B]            
Get:61 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [7,388 B]           
Get:62 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages [4,900 B]           
Get:63 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [4,611 B]            
Get:64 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [2,367 B]           
Get:65 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg [316 B]                     
Get:66 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages [502 B]             
Get:67 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [502 B]              
Get:68 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [245 B]             
Get:69 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release [14.0 kB]                       
Get:70 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [15.6 kB]
Get:71 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release [15.1 kB]                       
Get:72 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [339 kB]
Get:73 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release [14.0 kB]                       
Get:74 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages [4,436 B]           
Get:75 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [4,456 B]            
Get:76 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages [765 B]             
Get:77 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [765 B]              
Get:78 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [684 B]             
Get:79 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages [707 B]             
Get:80 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [707 B]              
Get:81 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [13.4 kB]
Get:82 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [359 kB]
Get:83 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en [6,947 B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_IN                     
Get:84 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en [3,699 B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_IN                     
Get:85 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [180 kB]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:86 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources [8,672 B]    
Get:87 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources [28 B] 
Get:88 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources [33.2 kB]
Get:89 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources [1,898 B]
Get:90 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages [9,787 B]
Get:91 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages [28 B]
Get:92 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages [39.8 kB]
Get:93 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,571 B]
Get:94 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages [9,814 B]
Get:95 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages [28 B]
Get:96 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages [39.8 kB]
Get:97 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages [1,552 B]
Get:98 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en [5,843 B]
Get:99 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en [1,215 B]
Get:100 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en [28 B]
Get:101 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en [34.6 kB]
Get:102 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release [58.5 kB]                  
Get:103 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources [1,064 kB]            
Get:104 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources [5,433 B]       
Get:105 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources [6,399 kB]        
Get:106 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources [174 kB]        
Get:107 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages [1,350 kB]     
Get:108 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages [13.0 kB]
Get:109 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages [5,859 kB] 
Get:110 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages [5,859 kB] 
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IN                 
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_IN           
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_IN           
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_IN             
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Fetched 14.6 MB in 1min 29s (162 kB/s)                                         
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: I'll try that solution and repost!

Answer (score 2):

Type the following command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

update

```
sudo apt-get update
```