# sudo apt-get update not working!

Tags: 18.04, apt, updates

When I'm trying to run "sudo apt-get update" on ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I'm getting error in below comments:

```
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                         
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                                   
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                      
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                     
Ign:7 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  InRelease                                                              
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                           
Err:9 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  Release                                                                
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:113:80c0:8::13 80]
Hit:10 http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty InRelease                                                                                                   
Hit:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                                   
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/slgobinath/safeeyes/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                      
Hit:14 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                  
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                       
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
Reading package lists... Done                       
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have tried below links, but nothing worked.
[apt- sudo apt-get update not working!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738160/apt-sudo-apt-get-update-not-working)
["sudo apt-get update" is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960182/sudo-apt-get-update-is-not-working)

Please help me in resolving the error!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: @ N0rbert. This didn't solve my problem. But thanks for sharing.

Comment: What exactly did you try, and what happened when you tried them?

Comment: The openSuse repo does not exist: **Resource is no longer available!** So remove it. Try by opening in the browser: `http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home`

Answer (score 4):

You can change the repository that figures there

```
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04
```

,that dont have a release file for this one:

```
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_18.04/
```

If that doesn't work, you should delete that repository, i tried to enter there and i found that it donest exist anymore(the version is no longer supported), sor you could try the 18.04 or delete the first

You can search a way to add repositories searching on google how do that for you SO(i think that is Xubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Yes, both of the repositories don't exist. 
I tried to remove the repository(Software & update > Other Software > Select the link > Remove > Close)  in the error i.e.,

http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04

and it solved the problem. Hence, sudo apt-get update is running fine now.

But I am thinking how do I know which repositories should be added to that list. Are there any standards/ general repos?

Comment: Yes, there are "official" repositories for each distribution, and they would have "mirrors" from different contries. I suggest you search in google mirrors that are near to your country(.in is from india i think), and try to get them. I give here an example of some US. mirros, and a description that gives you some idea of the structure of the type of repositories you will find: https://gist.github.com/rhuancarlos/c4d3c0cf4550db5326dca8edf1e76800