# Ubuntu 18.04 "sudo apt update" not working. Getting a lot of "Target packages is configured multiple times"

Tags: 18.04, apt, updates

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://repos.del.extreme-ix.org/ubuntu bionic InRelease                  
Hit:4 http://repos.del.extreme-ix.org/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease          
Hit:5 http://repos.del.extreme-ix.org/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease        
Hit:6 http://repos.del.extreme-ix.org/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease         
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease            
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Hit:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease             
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: **.***.**.** 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
```

`sudo apt upgrade` works fine.

I have tried **Select Best Server** in Software and Update but it did not work.

I have also tried the solution from this page: [apt- sudo apt-get update not working!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738160/apt-sudo-apt-get-update-not-working)

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The PPA error is because a user with `sudo` access on your system, added it but support for it ended with 17.04 thus it should not have been added; It needs removal,, and possibly replacing with a source which provide bionic/18.04 support if required by users. PPA's are 3rd party so responsibility on fitness for purpose, trustworthy & good for your system are all on you.

Comment: Which PPA should I remove?

Comment: The one in the error message, ie. http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/  which I copied from your messages into a browser to look at what releases it supports. This should be done by users before adding (to see if still maintained, yes it's got what I consider very trustworthy people who worked on it, but the fact that development ceased in 2016 except for a minor translation file is a warning...  thus it shouldn't have been added to a bionic/18.04 release in my opinion - https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sdk-team

Comment: All the statements after "Reading package lists... Done" are still there when I try "sudo apt update". I removed the PPA.

Comment: The duplicates are because a user (with `sudo` rights) added them, eg. /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list contains records also found in the main sources.list The /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory is empty on a new install, so those were added post-install without check to see if already added (those entries someone also added to /etc/apt/sources.list file too). I'd delete the extra entries added to /etc/apt/sources.list myself (`vscode` isn't a Ubuntu entry so belongs in sources.list.d in my opinion) but which you delete is up to you. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You have the same ppa or other source mentioned more than once in the sources. In particular it seems that you have duplicate entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list`.

Check the files for duplicate entries and remove the extra ones.

To make sure you don't end up with broken .list files, make backup copies of both files before editing them.