# Chrome - apt-get update Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2 Hash Sum mismatch

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, google-chrome, 64-bit

I'm running **Chrome 50.0.2661.102 (64-bit)** on **Ubuntu 16.04 x64** and today `sudo apt-get update` failed with the following message:

```
...
Err:28 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
  Hash Sum mismatch
...
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 3B068FB4789ABE4AEFA3BB491397BC53640DB551 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here is my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

And lines 23-25 of `/opt/google/chrome/cron/google-chrome`

```
# sources.list setting for google-chrome updates.
REPOCONFIG="deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main"
REPOCONFIGREGEX="deb (\[arch=[^]]*\bamd64\b[^]]*\][[:space:]]*) https?://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main"
```

As suggested by the answers to [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/q/41605/543097), I tried

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

but problem remains.

Is the issue related to Google servers or is it somehow a configuration problem on my side ?

**Update 1:** The problem seems to come from Google... Until they fix it,  either `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` should be removed or the `deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`  line should be commented out...

**Update 2:** The "Hash Sum mismatch" error has been fixed (but the "weak digest algorithm" warning is still there. This isn't a deal breaker for me since now apt-get returns 0 and I can run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade` without a problem)

Comment: I tried to remove the repos and reinstall, and now they give no install candidate.  However, I did remove it, and downloaded the .deb directly from Google and that seems to work fine for now.  My guess is there is a problem in the google repository.

Comment: Would I loose all my config, data and plugins when I `apt-get remove google-chrome-stable` before installing it from the `.deb` again ?

Comment: Mine seemed to stay OK.  I think the config files are stored in your home directory and if you don't purge google-chrome-stable when you remove, it should be fine.

Comment: Plus, when you install, if you sign in, it should prompt you to sync all back into it.

Comment: I've just reinstalled it (using GDebi): same problem.

Comment: You need to remove the repository as well from the system.  Probably the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` file needs to be deleted.

Comment: Well, I've just did that too. Now chrome is installed, (btw, no data/config/package lost) `apt-get update` finishes successfully but `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` has not been created by the setup process...

Comment: Yeah, it won't create it.  This might need to have a bug filed with google to have it fixed, but for now this seems to work.

Comment: Actually looks like they just fixed it.  I did not get the error this time.  =)

Comment: Yes, thanks for notifying me. I have updated the post now.

Comment: You're very welcome!  =)

Answer (score 9):

I'm getting this same exact error "hash sum mismatch" on both Ubuntu 14.04 as well as Ubuntu 16.04, and only 16.04 complains about the encryption algorithm.

The source of this problem seems to be twofold:

1. apt deprecated sha1 recently, which explains the warnings we have been getting from the google repo since the latest LTS was released.
2. Google was going to provide a fix for the "weak digest algorithm"
   warnings at some point: (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=596074)

The following is *speculative*, but seems to fit the symptoms we're seeing:

**Google may have rolled out new hashes that no longer match the GPG pub key signatures that everyone is using, presumably these are no longer sha1sums.  This might mean they've created hashes for new keys, but have yet to publish new GPG pubkey sigs to go with them for the repo, hence the hash mismatch.**

*If* this turns out to be true, besides being incredibly annoying, there's not much we can do until Google gets their act together.

I suspect this is just a matter of time, and we should see a fix soon(ish),in the form of new GPG pubkey signatures we should be using.  It should be easy to add the latest ones with:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Assuming of course that the link to the new keys doesn't change; I'm going to be keeping an eye out for changes there.

If you're frustrated with the messages, you can disable them by commenting out the sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`.

`software-properties-gtk` will allow you to remove any of Google's existing signatures in the authentication tab, before adding the new ones.

*And* if you've deleted the repo files (like I did several times today) you can setup the repos properly by installing the .deb again, just make sure you set the repo_add_once variable to "true" in /etc/defaults/google-chrome.  The file should look like this:

```
repo_add_once="true"
repo_reenable_on_distupgrade="true"
```

This of course is **NOT** a fix for anything at the moment, but will configure everything properly again.  Also, last little caveat - the script that installs the repos usually has a copy of the GPG signature in it, so you might want to update the apt-key again before you do an apt-get update.

Here's hoping this problem goes away soon.

Comment: **UPDATE**:  The hash problem seems to have spontaneously gone away when I run apt-get update now.  Looks like google reverted the hash sums to what it was.

Comment: Looks like the problem may have been in the hash sig for either `google-chrome-beta` or `google-chrome-unstable`, it appears both have had updates, and now no more error.  Checked the hashes for the stable branch and they are identical.  Not sure what the deal is.  Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I had set this (I don't know why I would have set this) or if Google/Chrome had set this but `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` had the immutable flag set. When this is set it means a file cannot be changed or modified.

I don't know if this only affected me (in the event I set this myself for some reason) or if this is the root cause and was set by Google.

Run the command `lsattr /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`. If the 5th character is an `i` instead of a `-` than it means the immutable flag is set.

Immutable flag set: `----i--------e-- /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`

Immutable flag not set: `-------------e-- /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`

If the the immutable flag is set than you can fix this by running `sudo chattr -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list && sudo apt-get update`

Please let me know if this is set on your system in the comments. I can't imagine why I would have set it but if it is set on other peoples systems than I know this came from Google and not from me.

**UPDATE:** I compared `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` past and present since I use etckeeper and I do not see any changes to the file itself which makes me question the validity of the immutable bit however disabling the immutable bit does seem to have resolved the issue for me.

**UPDATE:** I manually re-enabled the immutable bit and then ran `sudo apt-get update` and it did not cause the problem to re-occur. I am wondering about the validity of my answer but I am looking forward to some feedback to determine if this did cause it. If it did than I am not sure why it did if the file wasn't changed.

Comment: I have manually removed then re-created the file when I reinstalled chrome. When I run `lsattr`, it seems that the immutable flag is not set.

Comment: @865719 if you could do that, it wasn't immutable in the first place.