# "Hash Sum mismatch" on google-talkplugin

Tags: apt, deb, google, google-talk

Very recently now, Google's repositories have been updated to fix the weak hash issue. After that, I am getting `Hash Sum mismatch` when I try to update the `google-talkplugin`:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  google-talkplugin
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 7 800 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12,3 kB disk space will be freed.
Get:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable/main amd64 google-talkplugin amd64 5.41.3.0-1 [7 800 kB]
Err:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable/main amd64 google-talkplugin amd64 5.41.3.0-1
  Hash Sum mismatch
Fetched 7 800 kB in 3s (2 114 kB/s)              
E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/pool/main/g/google-talkplugin/google-talkplugin_5.41.3.0-1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
```

How can I fix it?

I have already tried running [`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`](https://askubuntu.com/a/41618/31831).

**UPDATE**

I have commented on the previous bug's thread here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=596074#c48

Comment: This might be a recent bug, I see the same thing.

Comment: Do you use Firefox, or Chrom{e,ium}?

Comment: If deleting the list files and updating them again does not help (which you say you already tried), then it's most likely a bug on the package maintainers' side and you have to wait for them to fix it. Searching for a bug report about that and subscribing to it or filing a new one if it doesn't exist yet might speed up the process.

Comment: @dobey: Both. I am not sure how is that relevant to APT and the package though.

Comment: @wilx Because the plug-in is not required for Chrom{e,ium}, so if you don't need to use hangouts in Firefox, my suggestion would be to just delete the apt source and uninstall the plug-in. Then you won't get the problem from Google's broken packaging any more. :)

Answer (score 7):

I also got this error and found a workaround. just manualy download and install the .deb package from this link and the error is gone.

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_talk_plugin/stable/main/base/google-talkplugin

Comment: Won't that make it impossible to get updates from the PPA?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure about this.