# Unable to install skype on Ubuntu 16.04 64 Bit - Failed to fetch / Hash sum mismatch

Tags: apt, 16.04, skype

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 Bit . I am unable to install Skype . It gives me the following error .

```
E: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/cpp-5_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gst-plugins-base1.0/libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0_1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
```

I have seen [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error) and already tried various commands and operations:

1. I tried `sudo apt clean` , `update` , `upgrade` command .
2. I tried switching the Servers .

Comment: I know that , But i mention i tried all the possible solutions . But nothing works . I have already seen the Duplicate of my question ,.

Comment: Well, "all the possible solutions" means exactly nothing as you don't list what exactly you tried. Therefore I translate this to "I tried nothing yet but want my question to look better". If I would take that phrase seriously, how should anybody be able to help you if you already tried everything possible?

Comment: Actually i meant to say all the possible solutions out in the internet .

Comment: *facepalm* - Sorry, but "all possible solutions on the internet" is equally undefined and meaningless as your previous wording. The internet is huge and I strongly doubt you visited *every* single website that exists and tried *every* single possibly related approach. However, if you had done that, why would you think that we can add anything to what you already say you tried?

Comment: New problems arise everyday and new answers to those problems . I may have said that wrong .  Maybe someone facing the problem and he/she fixed the problem in a different approach .  Don't know why you are making it such a big deal ? I may have said something silly . You can ignore that part and help me if you can .

Comment: Well, you could try and switch to a different repository server mirror. Open System Settings → Software & Updates, go to Ubuntu Software tab and pick a different server in the Download From list.

Comment: And still "I tried everything" is a meaningless sentence, because we need to know what *exactly* you tried. You surely found other results if you researched the issue than everyone of us. I'm just saying that you must always describe stuff relevant to your question as detailed and explicit as possible, we can't read minds here yet.

Comment: Yes i already tried that too . It was Main server in the beginning , then i switched it to US Sever . Still facing the problem .

Comment: @ByteCommander I sure will keep this in mind . As i am new user in Askubuntu , i made this mistake . Thanks for your advise . I will try to describe all the relevant stuffs from next time .

Comment: And how should I have known that you already tried multiple servers? You did not tell me. See the problem with your vague statement? Please [edit] your question and list everything you tired so far in detail (exact actions and commands) before we go on wasting our precious time (but especially the time of everyone attempting to answer) with suggesting stuff you already tried.

Comment: Thanks. But those two points you mentioned now are very far away from "all possible solutions", even the linked question has far more different answers. Try `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* ; sudo apt-get update`

Comment: What I think is happening is that you're installing `skype` from `apt-get` right ? You need to get rid of it.  Skype in Ubuntu repositories is kind of old and broken. There is new skype for linux (alpha) .  It installs fairly nice, so far haven't had issues with it: https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-for-Linux-Alpha-and-calling-on-Chrome-amp-Chromebooks/td-p/4434299

Comment: @Serg The Ubuntu repository `skype` might be old, but is working fine once you managed to install it. I'm not necessarily saying it's better or worse than this new Linux alpha version, but it is not deprecated yet and can still be used.

Comment: @ByteCommander eh, i just prefer path of lesser resistance. New skype manages to install without dependency problems , etc.  But to each their own