# "Hash sum mismatch" when upgrading 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, apt

I want to upgrade Ubuntu from verison 14.04 to 16.04.

Everything is fine until it reaches getting new packages. When it says "downloading new packages 2039 out of 2043" an error is appearing. It cannot download the the package. There is error downloading file:

```
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qtwebkit-opensource-src/libqt5webkit5_5.5.1+dfsg-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb Hash Sum mismatch
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fonts-liberation/fonts-liberation_1.07.4-1_all.deb Hash Sum mismatch
```

Comment: Are you behind an internet proxy? Are you (or the network you are in) using a caching apt proxy? If so, then sometimes you can fix this by using `wget` to download the package directly and then place it in `/var/cache/apt/archives` (or the equivalent on Ubuntu 16.04). It fixed most of the issues I had with hash sum mismatch issues.

Comment: I am also affected by the same issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)