# I cannot install google-musicmananger-beta via apt-get (Hash sum mismatch error)

Tags: apt

Please refer to the "screen capture" below.

When trying to install google-musicmanager-beta via apt-get, I get a "Hash sum mismatch". Any ideas what could be wrong?

edit1: I deleted all contents of the apt cache and run apt-get update again and still not working.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

edit2: I downloaded the .deb file shown when running apt-get install and I was able to successfully install it!

screen capture

```
root@chiyo-VirtualBox:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list 
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb/ stable main

root@chiyo-VirtualBox:~# apt-get --quiet --yes update
Hit:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb stable InRelease
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb stable Release
Fetched 94.5 kB in 1s (61.3 kB/s)
Reading package lists...

root@chiyo-VirtualBox:~# apt-get --quiet --yes install google-musicmanager-beta
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libqt4-opengl libqtwebkit4
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  google-musicmanager-beta libqt4-opengl libqtwebkit4
0 to upgrade, 3 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 4,362 kB/13.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 55.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb stable/main amd64 google-musicmanager-beta amd64 1.0.243.1116-r0 [4,362 kB]
Err:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb stable/main amd64 google-musicmanager-beta amd64 1.0.243.1116-r0
  Hash Sum mismatch
Fetched 4,362 kB in 2s (1,971 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb/pool/main/g/google-musicmanager-beta/google-musicmanager-beta_1.0.243.1116-r0_amd64.deb Hash Sum mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

root@chiyo-VirtualBox:/var/lib/apt/lists$ cat dl.google.com_linux_musicmanager_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages
Package: google-musicmanager-beta
Version: 1.0.243.1116-r0
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: Google Music Team <googleplay-support-music@google.com>
Installed-Size: 16490
Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.14.0)
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.16), libexpat1 (>= 2.0.1), libflac8 (>= 1.3.0), libgcc1 (>
= 1:4.1.1), libidn11 (>= 1.13), libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3), libqtcore4 (>= 4:4
.8.0), libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0), libqtwebkit4, libstdc++6 (>= 4.6), libvorbisfile
3 (>= 1.1.2), xdg-utils (>= 1.0.2)
Conflicts: google-musicmanager
Replaces: google-musicmanager
Provides: google-musicmanager
Section: net
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/main/g/google-musicmanager-beta/google-musicmanager-beta_1.0.243
.1116-r0_amd64.deb
Size: 4361868
SHA1: 8a8e9434f3ccb778c761f983ec1196ad4a4701c0
MD5sum: 4537c0f2bdf57eee7d576b7b0a42d083
Description: Google Music uploader.
 Google Music Manager is a simple application for adding the music files on your computer to your Music library.
```

Comment: There is a whole series of solutions in reply to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error?rq=1). I'd say: try the relevant options and upvote the one that works for you!

Comment: I also get this error -- still. @mrjayviper did you fix it?