# Can't update Ubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10

Tags: updates, 17.04, update-manager, do-release-upgrade, 17.10

I have tried using both GUI and terminal but the error occurs due to in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/multiverse/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/d1f9e7ec6489f3540ddd3399c345799e46d2e1213570f510ca41bd12d5b9407e (link to this file is the second link in the log below as I can't have more than 2 links in a question yet) having wrong hash while its actual hash is 8da861b95323d6b98fdcc24324eee84baa90aa6159cf9b7134fe81432639e14e.

Part of the log where I most likely think error occurs when I do `sudo do-release-upgrade` :

> Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/multiverse i386
>   Packages           Hash Sum mismatch Hashes of expected file:
>
> - Filesize:142776 [weak]
> - SHA256:d1f9e7ec6489f3540ddd3399c345799e46d2e1213570f510ca41bd12d5b9407e
> - SHA1:16f5314466b815e49a6b53124ba88bd434304b9e [weak]
> - MD5Sum:c7b94987695731eb16b07c5bb0c8311d [weak]
>
> Hashes of received file:
>
> - SHA256:8da861b95323d6b98fdcc24324eee84baa90aa6159cf9b7134fe81432639e14e
> - SHA1:9ecda16f6e859d480eacde0b06800c58f7d7a43e [weak]
> - MD5Sum:f8c8486e5ab253cb02209022ff3d0dc1 [weak]
> - Filesize:142776 [weak]
>
> Last modification reported: Wed, 18 Oct 2017 08:50:51 +0000 Release file created at: Thu, 19 Oct 2017 12:55:45
>   +0000
>
> Fetched 379 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
>
> Error during update
>
> A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
>   network problem, please check your network connection and retry.
>
> E:Failed to fetch 
>   http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/multiverse/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/d1f9e7ec6489f3540ddd3399c345799e46d2e1213570f510ca41bd12d5b9407e
>   Hash Sum mismatch  Hashes of expected file:
>
> - Filesize:142776 [weak]
> - SHA256:d1f9e7ec6489f3540ddd3399c345799e46d2e1213570f510ca41bd12d5b9407e
> - SHA1:16f5314466b815e49a6b53124ba88bd434304b9e [weak]
> - MD5Sum:c7b94987695731eb16b07c5bb0c8311d [weak]
>
> Hashes of received file:
>
> - SHA256:8da861b95323d6b98fdcc24324eee84baa90aa6159cf9b7134fe81432639e14e
> - SHA1:9ecda16f6e859d480eacde0b06800c58f7d7a43e [weak]
> - MD5Sum:f8c8486e5ab253cb02209022ff3d0dc1 [weak]
> - Filesize:142776 [weak]
>
> Last modification reported: Wed, 18 Oct 2017 08:50:51 +0000  Release file created at: Thu, 19 Oct 2017 12:55:45
>   +0000  , E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or  old ones used instead.
>
> Restoring original system state
>
> Aborting Reading package lists... Done     Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done

I am sure there are no network issues. I have even tried to update my system using Live CD/ISO but those don't work either. The ISO doesn't have any `cdromupgrade` file and the Live CD when booted for some unknown reason grays out the update option leaving me with only the 2 erase options and something else option.

Comment: Change the update source from `in` (guess thats India?) to the main server and check if the problem persists.

Comment: Tested with the main server but still same error

Comment: File a bug report but you will have to wait until this is resolved with the repositories.

Comment: Can in anyway I specifically set it to ignore this file's checksum?

Comment: Bog report filed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1725336

Comment: This answer solved the problem for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/779924/341706 You just need to update with a different compression method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer solved the problem for me: [askubuntu.com/a/779924/341706](https://askubuntu.com/a/779924/341706) . You just need to update with a different compression method. Thanks [@c0smicVorTeX](https://askubuntu.com/users/341706/c0smicvortex)