# Update Ubuntu 17.04 from ISO

Tags: updates, live-usb, 17.04, live-cd, 17.10

I want to update my Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 while preserving most of the system settings. I currently can't update it using *update-manager* and also `do-release-upgrade` due to [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966739/cant-update-ubuntu-from-17-04-to-17-10) so I thought if I could update using Live CD but when I booted the Live CD and went through the installer to selection page for some reason there were only 3 options available:

- Erase Ubuntu 17.04 and install Ubuntu 17.10 alongside Windows
- Erase disk and install Ubuntu
- Something else

Rest all options were grayed out. While searching on the internet, I came across `cdromupgrade` but that doesn't exist in the ISO. Is there any way I can update from the ISO/Live CD?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can update from the ISO/Live CD?

From the installer the only method that works:

- "something else"
- Mount / and do not pick "format" if /home/ is part of /.
- Mount /home and do not pick "format".

---

You can also make a backup of /home/ (copy /home to an USB)(always a good idea to do). All your settings will be there (browser bookmarks for instance) so you could also re-install and then pick the settings from that backup.

Comment: Is it the same as updating using the default upgrade option in Live CD/`cdromupgrade`? Or are there any disadvantages to using this method over the default methods?

Comment: What do you mean by that? The 1st method I mentioned works but I consider that a last resort. When I read this: " I currently can't update it using update-manager"  I would 1st think: so wait until you can. Nobody is forcing you to install 17.10. And my 2nd thought: you need to rethink the way you set up your machine. My setup allows me to -always- reinstall my system since all the things that matter are on a partition /discworld I simply mount. My / and /home are empty. And I have a script with a bunch of "sudo apt install"  and "sudo apt purge" commands to change it into what I want.

Comment: I also have a backup on my data partition that holds a copy of settings I want to keep. My `.config/users-dirs.dirs`  is there. So are my bookmarks, my password safe and some other things. `cdromupgrade` is from the time we had an "alternate installer".