# Repository failures

Tags: 18.04, apt, updates, repository

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop. When I tried to update with `sudo apt update` I got several errors as shown below.

```
<Ign:14 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                     
Get:14 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2.468 B]              
Err:14 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                      
  Hash Sum incorreto
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:2468 [weak]
   - SHA256:fce00e1c53ec013db87069774baa183a48794b3005a6b9d7155673859633d7ac
   - SHA1:d5383d0d6f428f77103c4407f0f4926d39f6a16b [weak]
   - MD5Sum:2d3999b13bf701c066ab6c7fbdc233c0 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:3dc0b84dccb52b1ef3d90931a0250763ee3a0a448e785f1710a9c6332f9846e5
   - SHA1:9a6e154c6d54113618030896099807b89f3fff69 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:b3a157971e8805ed9174eeb515525af0 [weak]
   - Filesize:2468 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 11:18:56 +0000
  Release file created at: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 15:58:07 +0000
Hit:17 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease                                                      
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybolic/vineyard-testing/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                          
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/smartfinn/eve-ng-integration/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                      
Hit:20 http://deb.anydesk.com all InRelease                                                                                               
Hit:21 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease                                                                 
Downloaded 91,2 kB em 10s (8.927 B/s)                                                                                                            
Reading package list... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  Hash Sum incorreto
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:2468 [weak]
    - SHA256:fce00e1c53ec013db87069774baa183a48794b3005a6b9d7155673859633d7ac
    - SHA1:d5383d0d6f428f77103c4407f0f4926d39f6a16b [weak]
    - MD5Sum:2d3999b13bf701c066ab6c7fbdc233c0 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:3dc0b84dccb52b1ef3d90931a0250763ee3a0a448e785f1710a9c6332f9846e5
    - SHA1:9a6e154c6d54113618030896099807b89f3fff69 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:b3a157971e8805ed9174eeb515525af0 [weak]
    - Filesize:2468 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 11:18:56 +0000
   Release file created at: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 15:58:07 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old   
ones used instead.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error) and [Can't update Ubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/966739)

Answer (score 0):

You might have trouble with sources.
They can be checked and edited using this command:

`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

"gedit" can be "nano" or "vi" any other text editor you've got installed.

So you can do this: place # symbol before each suspicious source, than save the file and try to update packages via `sudo apt update`.