# When updating from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS into 22.04 LTS it shows network error.How to resolve this?

Tags: 20.04, updates, 22.04, do-release-upgrade

While updating my version it shows a network error even though I have a good internet connection

```
Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't update Ubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966739/cant-update-ubuntu-from-17-04-to-17-10)