# Unable to upgrade to 17.10 from 17.04. I have attached the error message. I have removed all the apps except those were preinstalled

Tags: apt, update-manager

Error "E:Failed to fetch http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/multiverse/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/d1f9e7ec6489f3540ddd3399c345799e46d2e1213570f510ca41bd12d5b9407e Hash Sum mismatch Hashes of expected file: - Filesize:142776 [weak] - SHA256:d1f9e7ec6489f3540ddd3399c345799e46d2e1213570f510ca41bd12d5b9407e - SHA1:16f5314466b815e49a6b53124ba88bd434304b9e [weak] - MD5Sum:c7b94987695731eb16b07c5bb0c8311d [weak] Hashes of received file: - SHA256:8da861b95323d6b98fdcc24324eee84baa90aa6159cf9b7134fe81432639e14e - SHA1:9ecda16f6e859d480eacde0b06800c58f7d7a43e [weak] - MD5Sum:f8c8486e5ab253cb02209022ff3d0dc1 [weak] - Filesize:142776 [weak] Last modification reported: Wed, 18 Oct 2017 08:50:51 +0000 Release file created at: Thu, 19 Oct 2017 12:55:45 +0000 , E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRAmq.png)

Comment: Try changing the server.

Comment: Tried but upgrade failed with same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)

Answer (score 0):

It can be some bad cache between you and the servers.

Please try:

`sudo apt -o Acquire::https::No-Cache=True -o Acquire::http::No-Cache=True update`

In a terminal.

Comment: Tried this and started upgrading to 17.10 but failed again with the same error