# sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove . i used this command and seems this error

Tags: sudo

```
E: Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/06037c30d4089fb5eb7743e3e8b8f0844c499231dcfc81e7e2ed8beb2e170606  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Related, maybe a duplicate: [Trouble downloading packages list due to a “Hash sum mismatch” error](https://askubuntu.com/q/41605/301745)

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty long chained command. Break it into smaller chunks and execute them separately, like this:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt autoremove
```

Work through each step, fixing any issues as they arise.

Regarding the error you're getting, I suspect it's coming from the first command. Since you've chained the commands with &&, then the error is preventing the rest of the commands from executing, as it should. The first thing I'd do is check the contents of the /etc/apt/sources.list file. I suspect you have an overly complex url for the update site. If you see this in the file:

```
http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/06037c30d4089fb5eb7743e3e8b8f0844c499231dcfc81e7e2ed8beb2e170606
```

then make a backup of the file, then edit that line to remove the hashy thing that apt is complaining about. Like this:

```
http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/
```

Then re-try the update...

```
$ sudo apt update
```

Mine says `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted`. I'm not sure what the "np" is for in yours, but mine is "us".

The functional content of my Ubuntu 17.10 sources.list file (minus comments) is:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security multiverse
```

Comment: The "np" stands for Nepal.

Comment: A line in the sources list that's just a URL would be invalid, so I don't think this is what's causing the issue.

Comment: wjandrea, you are correct, I was just focusing on the part that needed editing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean apt cache with `sudo apt-get clean`
2. Update package lists with `sudo apt-get update`
3. Resume installation with `sudo apt-get install -f`