# Error while installing Firefox

Tags: apt, firefox

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. While installing Firefox, this error is shown:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firefox
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 44.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 176 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 firefox amd64 58.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [44.5 MB]
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 firefox amd64 58.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                                  
  Hash Sum mismatch
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 firefox amd64 58.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [44.5 MB]                        
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 firefox amd64 58.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                                  
  Hash Sum mismatch
Fetched 88.9 MB in 2min 23s (621 kB/s)                                                                                                         
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_58.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

How can I fix "Hash Sum mismatch"?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing all the content of `/var/lib/apt/lists` directory, you can use this command:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Then execute this command:

```
sudo apt update
```

And finally, try to install `firefox` again:

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

If this doesn't work, you can try:

Settings → Software & Updates → Ubuntu Software: Download from: Change `Local` to `Main Server`, or any other Server that is close to you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry. But it didn't work. I have tried it before...

Comment: Try this: Settings → Software & Updates → Ubuntu Software: Download from: Change Local to Main Server.

Comment: I isn't working.. Same as before...

Comment: I found [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error) where you cand see various solutions, try them and let me know if it works.

Comment: Finally worked for this download server: Russian Federation->mirror.logol.ru

Comment: Good to hear that, I will add the answer to my post.

Comment: I solved my problem and credit goes to you! It's it too funny?

Comment: Well, actually I provided you with the instructions on how to change the `Download from` source, after you tried with some servers, finally it worked with a Russian server.

Comment: I live in Bangladesh and there are Ubuntu servers too. Russia isn't my closest server.

Comment: The best option is to choose a server that is close to you, but you can choose any server in the world.