# apt Failed to fetch, File has unexpected size

Tags: apt, 18.04, raspberrypi, multiverse

One of my Pi's is reporting the below errors when performing `apt update`/`apt-get update`:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic/multiverse/source/Sources.xz  File has unexpected size (181064 != 2744). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:2744 [weak]
    - SHA256:20434afedac422302fd0fcd17ed5aa35cc9cd66bba2d75daba96a2b788542036
    - SHA1:4f85e4357cb0dd6a7b378368419ca53f96dbe971 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:d010ff44056900efeec87e97ccdd9982 [weak]
   Release file created at: Sun, 04 Aug 2019 04:39:28 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic/restricted/source/Sources.xz
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic/restricted/binary-arm64/Packages.xz
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic/restricted/i18n/Translation-en.xz
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic/multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages.xz
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en.xz
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've read plenty of times that people say to "remove" the repository, or "wait", however, I have 2 identical RPis, and one doesn't have a problem connecting to the repositories. I've also seen people say to "wait" a few hours, but this has been going on for a week now, and it's an official Ubuntu repository (multiverse) that appears to be erroring.

Both have the same repositories, no additional ones in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Both are running Ubuntu 18.04 Server. The 2 Pis are built to be the same, they even replicate things to each other (such as OpenLDAP), and were working fine for months.

Any ideas why one Pi is having trouble?

Comment: Would [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error) help?

Comment: Spot on @guillermochamorro. Feel free to vote to close/flag as a duplicate. Apparently I was being *too* specific with my searches. Many thanks.

Comment: I think your question is valid, given that the error you show is different. Maybe you can answer your own question :)