# Lubuntu 20.04 having trouble upgrading due to apparent "Hash Sum Mismatch"

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, upgrade, lubuntu

I installed Lubuntu 20.04 today (I did checksum on the iso image and it was absolutely fine) and when I started updating and upgrading stuff, I found many things weren't upgrading. Initially it showed that I had a problem with the internet, but my internet was fine. After that, I ran sudo apt-get update, sudo apt update, sudo apt-get upgrade and sudo apt upgrade (I learned these commands from the internet and I don't really know much about them other than that they upgrade and update things).

Until sudo apt-get upgrade, everything was fine but when I ran sudo apt upgrade, more than 400MB of upgrades were not happening. At the bottom was an error message which suggested I run sudo apt upgrade --fix-missing. This helped a lot and most things were upgraded. But still, some stuff aren't upgrading at all. I ran the command several times and rebooted my laptop but still nothing. Here is what it says:

```
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-5.4.0-42 all 5.4.0-42.46 [11.0 MB]
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-5.4.0-42 all 5.4.0-42.46
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:7a21ab1e62daf2176f35c91670c81811afbc93fa8814756f92268f2023868c49
   - SHA1:3771f59745f82f83adc6bdf5bc048dc163c56d3a [weak]
   - MD5Sum:4969040e94112be4f8ba30c14f773cca [weak]
   - Filesize:10951448 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:f66f96511478efca3ee58a7f8545ccc511ae8d79d23e03d64cc40b4a5ce196fd
   - SHA1:e2bf94476aeba917c2741c5367e94ea09cb68056 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:2fc3eb37eef5f97a1e4998a5f10dfc06 [weak]
   - Filesize:10951448 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Fri, 10 Jul 2020 11:10:04 +0000
Fetched 11.0 MB in 2s (5,297 kB/s)                
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-5.4.0-42_5.4.0-42.46_all.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:7a21ab1e62daf2176f35c91670c81811afbc93fa8814756f92268f2023868c49
    - SHA1:3771f59745f82f83adc6bdf5bc048dc163c56d3a [weak]
    - MD5Sum:4969040e94112be4f8ba30c14f773cca [weak]
    - Filesize:10951448 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:f66f96511478efca3ee58a7f8545ccc511ae8d79d23e03d64cc40b4a5ce196fd
    - SHA1:e2bf94476aeba917c2741c5367e94ea09cb68056 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:2fc3eb37eef5f97a1e4998a5f10dfc06 [weak]
    - Filesize:10951448 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Fri, 10 Jul 2020 11:10:04 +0000
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Everytime I open my laptop, I get a message to upgrade and everytime it fails to do so.

Comment: FYI: The commands `sudo apt update` or `sudo apt-get update` both update your machines software lists (ie. what packages are available for your system from the sources/repositories you have enabled). Both commands do the same thing, so it's one or the other. Likewise `sudo apt upgrade` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` do almost the same thing; being alternatives.  `apt` is a more modern tool that will eventually replace `apt-get`, but still can't do everything `apt-get` does, thus why both are still included.

Comment: Please copy & paste the text from commands & error messages into your question, and not providing picture of text, text is easier to read, and we can copy & paste from text to look up details in our responses to you (we can't do that from pictures).

Comment: @karel I tried this solution, still the same

Comment: @guiverc I did what you said

Comment: Are you behind a proxy that might fiddle with the downloaded content?

Comment: @RobertKlemme I didn't really understand your question. What is proxy? And no, I don't usually download any content let alone fiddle with it. I don't have much technical knowledge

Comment: [This link](https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/45380/ubuntu-fixing-hash-sum-mismatch-while-downloading-updates-or-ubuntu-sdk/) should get your issue resolved. It will take a few minutes so follow the directions *carefully*.

Comment: @KGIII frustrated I changed my OS to Linux Mint in hopes of fixing it. Got the same problem with those same packages. Then I did what your link said: change the server. And yes! It fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: Until you're back on an *official flavor* of Ubuntu, you're considered off-topic. Mint is derived from Ubuntu, but is not actually an official flavor and so we're not allowed to offer support on this particular site. Either way, I'm glad you got it sorted and I'm glad I could help. If you feel like going back to Lubuntu, it's not a difficult process.

Comment: @SoumyaneelManna if you do not know what a HTTP proxy is and this is your private account chances are that this is not the issue. :-) Short version: a HTTP proxy sits between your client and every web site that you access. This is often used for caching or filtering the traffic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)