# sudo apt update failed

Tags: apt

```
Err:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:762382 [weak]
   - SHA256:6992cdbbeec75ab9a81f82dfe79b787bbe0da0587ddbb71090e3f5a1d6f14794
   - SHA1:c8ad07aa2316c5db1251db7ba3c8cc83d74deded [weak]
   - MD5Sum:e8523de342151179aac680d249b86bed [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:ee0640fcd2f7494c1e038f2aa14b91f3e4bcd1a7262052e981b40f5cabf1d22a
   - SHA1:c8ad07aa2316c5db1251db7ba3c8cc83d74deded [weak]
   - MD5Sum:e8523de342151179aac680d249b86bed [weak]
   - Filesize:762382 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Tue, 29 Sep 2020 00:30:01 +0000
  Release file created at: Tue, 29 Sep 2020 01:31:09 +0000
Fetched 218 kB in 3s (83.8 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-updates_universe_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.xz  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:762382 [weak]
    - SHA256:6992cdbbeec75ab9a81f82dfe79b787bbe0da0587ddbb71090e3f5a1d6f14794
    - SHA1:c8ad07aa2316c5db1251db7ba3c8cc83d74deded [weak]
    - MD5Sum:e8523de342151179aac680d249b86bed [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:ee0640fcd2f7494c1e038f2aa14b91f3e4bcd1a7262052e981b40f5cabf1d22a
    - SHA1:c8ad07aa2316c5db1251db7ba3c8cc83d74deded [weak]
    - MD5Sum:e8523de342151179aac680d249b86bed [weak]
    - Filesize:762382 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Tue, 29 Sep 2020 00:30:01 +0000
   Release file created at: Tue, 29 Sep 2020 01:31:09 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

If that does not work try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error/41618#41618).

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to [flag](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) this question as a duplicate of the other once you earned 15 [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). If you have the reputation, don't forget to vote for the answer(s) there that you found useful!

Comment: @Melebius Thanks for the suggestion. I am still learning to provide answers to questions following the Codes of Conduct. In future, I'll make sure to follow your suggestion.

Comment: I try already but still can't, I got try other solution still can't work.

Comment: @JyeJye Have you tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error/41618#41618)?