# i am not able to install pip3 even though python3 is already installed

Tags: apt, package-management, python

i am not able to install pip3 in my ubuntu 20.04 . Python3 is already installed i tried many methods like

```
sudo apt update
```

```
    sudo apt get--fix-missing
```

```
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    python3 is already the newest version (3.8.2-0ubuntu2).
    python3 set to manually installed.
    The following additional packages will be installed:
      binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-9 gcc gcc-9 libalgorithm-diff-perl
      libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan5 libatomic1 libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcrypt-dev libctf-nobfd0
      libctf0 libexpat1-dev libfakeroot libgcc-9-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libpython3-dev libpython3.8-dev libquadmath0 libstdc++-9-dev libtsan0
      libubsan1 linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev python-pip-whl python3-distutils python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3.8-dev zlib1g-dev
    Suggested packages:
      binutils-doc debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-9-multilib gcc-9-doc gcc-multilib autoconf automake libtool flex bison gcc-doc
      gcc-9-multilib gcc-9-locales glibc-doc libssl-doc libstdc++-9-doc make-doc python-setuptools-doc
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu build-essential dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-9 gcc gcc-9 libalgorithm-diff-perl
      libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan5 libatomic1 libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcrypt-dev libctf-nobfd0
      libctf0 libexpat1-dev libfakeroot libffi-dev libgcc-9-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libpython3-dev libpython3.8-dev libquadmath0 libssl-dev
      libstdc++-9-dev libtsan0 libubsan1 linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev python-pip-whl python3-dev python3-distutils python3-pip
      python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3.8-dev zlib1g-dev
    0 upgraded, 45 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Need to get 10.0 MB/40.3 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 180 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    Get:1 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 g++-9 amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 [8,405 kB]
    Err:1 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 g++-9 amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04                                       
      Hash Sum mismatch
      Hashes of expected file:
       - SHA512:79cb3a67e312cf74daeee5510137829a6d9b665a03e90d5e0f5423264409b66f1f3322e0f7d82edd5dca5a244fa30b04d764058751593140349c9f32e3db5155
       - SHA256:a99683cae0408684c03c084b3315c9a06a3a6a76eea1dce2285735433f543eb1
       - SHA1:049974e6082a881619c1df7e5cb873637c871a01 [weak]
       - MD5Sum:ff8a03f0d99ee219c8cf07ca8ff5193c [weak]
       - Filesize:8405048 [weak]
      Hashes of received file:
       - SHA512:c61bec4c4456c100b77bef7b4c92d556505e592cef9a4007b8a0a9ff43d0efc4da94600c12b4150652da582314784ec2a6005f5b18b4a913ae4029e6b3a64e73
       - SHA256:01ed59cf86dcc993dc06f3a501063ee2de1dd20eb780e5f171dca70ee9fcf21f
       - SHA1:0084ddd3e7739927f8dee2aa148d81c5710dbb0e [weak]
       - MD5Sum:da3e8f447e600114b986c49ad3d2742a [weak]
       - Filesize:8405048 [weak]
      Last modification reported: Fri, 04 Sep 2020 13:24:41 +0000
    Get:2 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libssl-dev amd64 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.3 [1,582 kB]                           
    Get:3 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libffi-dev amd64 3.3-4 [57.0 kB]                                                
    Fetched 10.0 MB in 45s (224 kB/s)                                                                                                          
    E: Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-9/g++-9_9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
       Hashes of expected file:
        - SHA512:79cb3a67e312cf74daeee5510137829a6d9b665a03e90d5e0f5423264409b66f1f3322e0f7d82edd5dca5a244fa30b04d764058751593140349c9f32e3db5155
        - SHA256:a99683cae0408684c03c084b3315c9a06a3a6a76eea1dce2285735433f543eb1
        - SHA1:049974e6082a881619c1df7e5cb873637c871a01 [weak]
        - MD5Sum:ff8a03f0d99ee219c8cf07ca8ff5193c [weak]
        - Filesize:8405048 [weak]
       Hashes of received file:
        - SHA512:c61bec4c4456c100b77bef7b4c92d556505e592cef9a4007b8a0a9ff43d0efc4da94600c12b4150652da582314784ec2a6005f5b18b4a913ae4029e6b3a64e73
        - SHA256:01ed59cf86dcc993dc06f3a501063ee2de1dd20eb780e5f171dca70ee9fcf21f
        - SHA1:0084ddd3e7739927f8dee2aa148d81c5710dbb0e [weak]
        - MD5Sum:da3e8f447e600114b986c49ad3d2742a [weak]
        - Filesize:8405048 [weak]
       Last modification reported: Fri, 04 Sep 2020 13:24:41 +0000
    E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt install python3-pip`?

Comment: take a look please https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error