# Update failure due to checksum mismatch

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, security

I am using ubuntu 18.04. When I tried to update the software using `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, I get a checksum mismatch error:

```
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-4.15.0-144 all 4.15.0-144.148 [11.0 MB]
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-4.15.0-144 all 4.15.0-144.148
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA512:ab631e944879a603bce23fd40b9a959eb567e0e27b7c2ab34f7eff5c1722b3fed1747123f1682635d825a61a9ef070067330008a4134394d95fe2832cdf80882
   - SHA256:8bca25a9b8d9ef5c43b94dbd8e4aec36f77d7617cf524e1d8e89e4429927d383
   - SHA1:c15a145876ad7e6059fc24b86d8b7273a160c415 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:8f50bc4934fc62ba526f1d75244e0727 [weak]
   - Filesize:10956636 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA512:155fe310a3c19ba653d69e8bf797739ac27d9fc1a5cf140682dec7652c35c0af08b703e9c474f63500e9a7b44f6e3de4086caf7301cbae9cc8fe238fabfe3caa
   - SHA256:70985c1b1f8fb1013e6912a3e3ac7580ddb878f42f962c9328dbd99e8b633e68
   - SHA1:e05ac0266a1b6349489456caa234ae61cf69e315 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:98de1c987d3726787cd89cc6a45450ba [weak]
   - Filesize:10956636 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Thu, 13 May 2021 09:11:42 +0000
Fetched 11.0 MB in 5s (2,418 kB/s)                   
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.15.0-144_4.15.0-144.148_all.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:ab631e944879a603bce23fd40b9a959eb567e0e27b7c2ab34f7eff5c1722b3fed1747123f1682635d825a61a9ef070067330008a4134394d95fe2832cdf80882
    - SHA256:8bca25a9b8d9ef5c43b94dbd8e4aec36f77d7617cf524e1d8e89e4429927d383
    - SHA1:c15a145876ad7e6059fc24b86d8b7273a160c415 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:8f50bc4934fc62ba526f1d75244e0727 [weak]
    - Filesize:10956636 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA512:155fe310a3c19ba653d69e8bf797739ac27d9fc1a5cf140682dec7652c35c0af08b703e9c474f63500e9a7b44f6e3de4086caf7301cbae9cc8fe238fabfe3caa
    - SHA256:70985c1b1f8fb1013e6912a3e3ac7580ddb878f42f962c9328dbd99e8b633e68
    - SHA1:e05ac0266a1b6349489456caa234ae61cf69e315 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:98de1c987d3726787cd89cc6a45450ba [weak]
    - Filesize:10956636 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Thu, 13 May 2021 09:11:42 +0000
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I am curious to know what could be the root cause of this. Is there a suggestion on how to fix this?

**Update:**
I tried the suggestions related to clearing caches, changing mirros, etc mentioned in [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error), but they did not help.

Just to confirm the checksum of the file, I tried `wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.15.0-144_4.15.0-144.148_all.deb && md5sum linux-headers-4.15.0-144_4.15.0-144.148_all.deb` and it prints 98de1c987d3726787cd89cc6a45450ba, which is a different checksum as compared to `8f50bc4934fc62ba526f1d75244e0727` mentioned in the upgrade error message and https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/main/security/linux-headers-4.15.0-144. Why would the checksum change? Can the package files on the repositories be replaced after releasing?

Comment: What are the outputs of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt-get --fix-missing`? Please use edit to include these outputs

Comment: Tried `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing`, but getting the same error even after that when I try `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: @Nmath asked you to include the output from `sudo apt update` in your question as those output messages provide clues... As we cannot see that output, we can't see whatever you see.  Subsequent commands like `sudo apt-get --fix-missing` or `sudo apt-get upgrade` aren't helpful if the clues are in the first command `sudo apt update` (ie. are all expected lines there, no warnings, errors or missing lines of output ... why you were asked to add it to your question).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried some of the suggestions mentioned, but none of them helped yet. Tried the remaining ones.

Comment: The downloaded file from the ubuntu archive indeed has a different checksum. `wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.15.0-144_4.15.0-144.148_all.deb && md5sum linux-headers-4.15.0-144_4.15.0-144.148_all.deb` prints `98de1c987d3726787cd89cc6a45450ba` whereas the upgrade error message and https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/main/security/linux-headers-4.15.0-144 shows an expected md5 checksum `8f50bc4934fc62ba526f1d75244e0727`

Comment: check this links I hope these links work for you : https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64120030/hash-sum-mismatch-when-apt-get-update-ubuntu-20-04-vm-with-multipass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package downloaded from the official repo seems to be corrupted. I tried installing it manually by `dpkg -i linux-headers-4.15.0-144_4.15.0-144.148_all.deb` which gave an error that the package could not be decompressed.

I changed the download source to the [mirror of University of Arizona](http://mirror.arizona.edu/ubuntu/) and the upgrade worked after that. Some of the other mirrors could have worked too.