# 21.10 sudo apt update always reports hash mismatch

Tags: apt, updates

`sudo apt update` always reports it has mismatch errors, no matter which mirror is used. All suggested workarounds like `apt-get clean`, etc. do not help.

I would appreciate some ideas, Ubuntu 21.10 desktop runs as a VM in VM Fusion.

```
sudo apt update
Get:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease [10,4 kB]
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease                                                                                 
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease [270 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [112 B]
Err:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 Packages
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:1396112 [weak]
   - SHA256:3bd421210c26b7d66f5599c57e6a9c96a9dbc19596be48b1bacde5e6bf461207
   - SHA1:e3d4e72562ef8fb5c2400798a9b612ea57e426e5 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:e5fb2960ff175a9dec6a323ab06f053a [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:9cb47a4d87cf4d363d8b80bde50abe172b560dd8af99a343939439aece9d9733
   - SHA1:2f5f9efb94eb66d86340804fb084a1c6d1c08cbb [weak]
   - MD5Sum:32889de2629cb9d26174dd78cc301771 [weak]
   - Filesize:1396112 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Wed, 13 Oct 2021 19:31:05 +0000
  Release file created at: Thu, 14 Oct 2021 16:35:09 +0000
  
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/impish/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/3bd421210c26b7d66f5599c57e6a9c96a9dbc19596be48b1bacde5e6bf461207  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:1396112 [weak]
    - SHA256:3bd421210c26b7d66f5599c57e6a9c96a9dbc19596be48b1bacde5e6bf461207
    - SHA1:e3d4e72562ef8fb5c2400798a9b612ea57e426e5 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:e5fb2960ff175a9dec6a323ab06f053a [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:9cb47a4d87cf4d363d8b80bde50abe172b560dd8af99a343939439aece9d9733
    - SHA1:2f5f9efb94eb66d86340804fb084a1c6d1c08cbb [weak]
    - MD5Sum:32889de2629cb9d26174dd78cc301771 [weak]
    - Filesize:1396112 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Wed, 13 Oct 2021 19:31:05 +0000
   Release file created at: Thu, 14 Oct 2021 16:35:09 +0000
```

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the update server from Software and updates application worked for me
It normally happens due to internet gliches and the solution are to delete any sort of internet filter or if you are not using one change the server like i did