# apt update not working.. getting Hash Sum mismatch error - Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management

We have configured local server where we get the packages using apt-mirror and there client trying to pull packages using `apt update`:

```
Err:30 http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ubuntu/mirror/azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  
Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:12500 [weak]
   - SHA256:ffb0ba77d733b726e0dc35331cf1e03fe1ab8a297b705211f9d1fa28ed0ebc90
   - SHA1:fa4445298ccf0ac4baa0c4563731c34aab805c76 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:4771bd40550239c2d5b16c65ad2e8113 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:d2c1bfaebc00349c33b50d969ab6d8305e694cd5923dd82127da018efc66e050
   - SHA1:d559a78c31fb6b4734154c27713a3a5f47c47154 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:f8ec5ea7790713a1846e6ac781889155 [weak]
   - Filesize:12500 [weak]
```

We tried almost all solutions but still its not working.

```
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
apt clean
apt update
```

Also tried to remove the mirror and rerun the apt-mirror

I checked the md5sum hash value on server and client and it contains the same hash value not sure why the apt update taking the old hash values.

Any suggestion please.

Comment: In particular, did you try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/779924/1066942) (with a different compression method)?