# How to speed up `apt-get upgrade`? My network is slow

Tags: apt, upgrade

I wanted to upgrade faster. I already tried the `apt-get update` command.

As my network connection is slow, I couldn't be able to finish it.

After 49% I stopped the process by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Comment: If the network connection is slow, there's nothing you can do in Ubuntu to fix it, other than maybe playing with your DSL settings.

Comment: can i start upgrade from 49%?

Comment: If you still have that terminal open, running `fg` should restart the upgrade from where it was when you stopped it. Is this your question or your question is how to speed up `apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: You can't make stuff download faster if your internet is slow. You have to upgrade your plan if you need faster speeds.

Comment: pacman -Sy is more efficient that apt-get update. That's the main reason I ditched ubuntu. I'm on a slow mobile internet connection and all that apt-get does is spit a load of file lists at my screen and still manage to *not* update the package list after 2hrs or so.

Comment: Sometimes, I might not want to update all the packages, but just the package list, so that I can install an import package that gives 404 on apt-get install. I'd be better in hell than ubuntu in that situation. pacman -Sy simply downloads 4 files that are around 10 mb in total and you are ready

Answer (score 1):

### Use a Closer Mirror

- [Use apt's built in mirror support](https://askubuntu.com/a/37754/13247)
- [Use `netselect` to find the fastest available mirror](https://askubuntu.com/a/141536/13247)
- [Use a source list generator](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/)

### Auto-Download Security Updates

This may be benefitial to ensure you get the most important updates.  You could schedule the downloads for a time at which you don't use the Internet.  You can also adjust what is updated/downloaded automatically.

[`unattended-upgrades` instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/412/13247)

### Cache Packages

This will help if you have multiple machines on your network that will use the same updates

- [Apt-Cacher-Server](https://askubuntu.com/a/141536/13247)
- [Apt-Proxy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptProxy)

Answer (score 1):

## Install [apt-fast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52243/what-is-apt-fast-and-should-i-use-it) :

### Ubuntu 14.04 and above :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/myppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-fast
```

### Older distributions :

https://askubuntu.com/a/501905/458410

and then do :

```
sudo apt-fast update
sudo apt-fast upgrade
```

instead of `apt-get`.

## Create an alias :

- adding this line at the end of `/.bashrc`

  `alias apt-get='apt-fast'`
- launch

  `source /.bashrc`

and use apt-get as an alias for apt-fast:

```
apt-get update
```

Comment: It will not speed up `apt-get update`, but it will `upgrade` faster.