# Stuck at 0% [waiting for headers]

Tags: apt

On googling this error it seems that a lot of people are having this issue.

`apt-get upgrade` hangs at `0% [waiting for headers]` `apt-get install apache2` hangs at `0% [waiting for headers]`. Some `apt-get` commands are working, but only certain packages.

Any ideas? I don't think this is an issue with slow repos because I've had it up for a long while and it hasn't budged from 0%. I have edited `sources.list` but I removed the lines I added when this issue presented itself and it hasn't made a difference.

Any clues would be really useful.

Comment: Your Internet connection is disconnected...

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/156650/apt-get-update-very-slow-stuck-at-waiting-for-headers

read the mtu related answer, might be a help

Comment: I have tried all the solutions above, none of them work. I even tried a reboot at the command prompt, still the same,the 0% remains stuck forever. This is a serious issue because it hampers, slows down, or even prevents the user from installing and running programs or apps. I have never seen this happen in Ubuntu 14.04. I don't think it's caused by problems of Internet connection, because whenever the problem occurs I keep checking my browser by going to different websites and I am able to surf with no problem. I think it's a bug in Ubuntu 16.04 and it needs to be fixed fast.

Comment: For me it was because I was connected to my work VPN - couldn't connect to `deb.nodesource.com`, for instance. Disconnected from VPN - no problem. Connect again to VPN - problem. Won't be the source of the problem for everyone but if you are using a VPN and having this problem, try disconnecting. (can't post answer 'cause not enough rep)

Comment: I echo @drkvogel. As soon as I came off my VPN, quick and easy results. I also can't post because I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to change the server selecting update manager, definitions,downloading from, then select a server more near you. and then try again.

Edit: see this link on how to add it by editing sources.list.
[How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me)

Comment: any idea how to do this over ssh?

Comment: You edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to point to a different mirror

Answer (score 4):

The easiest approach consist of following  commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

&

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install <package_name>
```

Cheers

Let me know if it works

Comment: It worked for me..

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: @isomorphismes can you describe more ? maybe error or some screenshots

Comment: I posted the question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/439829/what-is-ubuntus-default-web-proxy-server

Comment: @isomorphismes i guess that is different issue seems like misconfiguration of proxy settings.

Comment: @iguarav May or may not be, depends on the next googler...

Answer (score 3):

I had to

```
sudo apt-key update
sudo apt-get update
```

From manpages:

> apt-key is used to manage the list of keys used by apt to authenticate
>          packages. Packages which have been authenticated using these keys will
>          be considered trusted.

Comment: `apt-key` does not magically make HTTP responses happen.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex It does however update the keyring which solved the problem for me.

Comment: The keyring isn't the problem with `0% [waiting for headers]`. The problem with `0% [waiting for headers]` is that the HTTP connection has stalled. Retrying the command will start a new HTTP connection, which might not get stuck. That (running `sudo apt-get update` again) is what solved the specific problem of `0% [waiting for headers]` for you. Keys are involved in the process **after** the HTTP connection is finished, when checking the finished downloads.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 22  (WLS).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a proxy server and have those settings in your user environment, try:

```
sudo -E apt update
```

to run the command as root but using your current user's environment.

Answer (score 1):

(Just reposting this as the original was inexplicably deleted)

I noticed this problem on a VM running Xenial in a data centre this week that had been running for 10 years ( upgraded through many Ubuntu LTS releases in that time).

I got tcpdump running to log requests to the URLs in /etc/apt/sources.list and didn't see any requests when I ran `apt-get update`

e.g.

```
 tcpdump -i eth0 host archive.ubuntu.com
```

If I tried to fetch from the host using wget , it worked fine

e.g.

```
wget archive.ubuntu.com/
```

Eventually I found that the ISP had set a proxy for apt in /etc/apt/apt.conf on my VM back in 2009 when the VM was first activated.

```
Acquire
{
  http 
  {
      Proxy "http://apt2.memset.net:3128";
  };
};
```

Evidently the proxy recently stopped working correctly.

I deleted the block above from my /etc/apt.conf and normality was restored