# Can't Install Packages ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, apt

I'm trying to install software by using apt-get and ubuntu software center UI, when I try the ubuntu software center it gets stuck saying installing and installs nothing and when I try the apt-get it gets stuck at the point "0% [Waiting for headers]"

I tried modifying sources.list file. I installed ubuntu this morning. Do you have any suggestions for me ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

edit : After a while, I get the error 502 bad gateway

Comment: Did you check your Internet connectivity?

Comment: What should I check specifically ? I'm asking this question via the machine I installed ubuntu. Doesn't me being able to browse through stack exchange indicate that there is no problem in my internet connection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're still able to access internet, try opening up the Software Center. Select Edit and Software Sources. From there make sure that the "Download from" is set to "Main Server". If not, select it and type `$ sudo apt-get update` to the terminal. Outcome still the same?

Comment: Yes it is, waiting for headers %0

Comment: Try this solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/94831/stuck-at-0-waiting-for-headers-apt

Comment: Forgot to write it, the servers in Turkey was faulty that day, that was my problem